# Array could not more than 7741 elements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using Node.js. I  have the following javascript code.

```
var length=9980;
this.distance= [];//hold distance
this.cost= [];   //hold time cost   

 console.log("before create distance and cost arrays"); 
 console.log("length" + length);   
 for(var i=0; i < length;i++)
 {   
    console.log("creating cost : " + i );       
    this.distance[i] = new Array(length);
    this.cost[i] = new Array(length);
 };
```

By this, I want to create 2 dimension array of

```
 distance, cost
```

as shown above.

The problem there is error reported.

[image]

Array should be able to hold millions of elements, but there is such error.

What is the problem?  How can I make it work?

Comment: maybe same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558989/node-js-heap-out-of-memory

Comment: Alim, I notice that you commonly add "please help" to your questions. Additions of this kind do not make questions more likely to be answered, and it may be interpreted as a form of begging. Please do also refrain from asking for urgency - that is not acceptable when addressing volunteers. Thank you!

Comment: It is already at at least `2 * (9,980 + 1) * 7,740 = 154,505,880` array elements there. That *is* millions. Those two arrays alone would take about 312 MB in Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are running into node's default memory limits.

Try adding running your node app with the --max_old_space_size= flag.

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096 app.js
```

According to http://prestonparry.com/articles/IncreaseNodeJSMemorySize/ the number is in megabytes so this should give you a memory cap of 4GB.

Comment: Actually, I tried that and did not work(even I set size as 10000). an array [9800][9800] may be to big.  Looks like I have to remove these arrays and find out some way which uses less memory.

Comment: The issue you are running into is probably because you are creating a two dimensional array. If you can make this work in a flat, one dimensional array, you will be way better off. An array of arrays is going to use a massive amount of memory. For each of those 9980 array elements, you are creating two additional 9980 arrays each with elements, and that seems to be a bit excessive. Try to handle all of this in one array or one object if possible.