# Javascript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, angular

I am getting the following error while using `npm start` for my angular pages.

```
C:\TPO\Client\Angular>ng serve
Your global Angular CLI version (1.3.2) is greater than your local
version (1.0.4). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng set --global warnings.versionMismatch=false".
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200 **
10% building modules 4/4 modules 0 active
<--- Last few GCs --->

  118169 ms: Mark-sweep 1348.4 (1404.3) -> 1348.1 (1404.3) MB, 1338.9 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  119374 ms: Mark-sweep 1348.1 (1404.3) -> 1348.1 (1404.3) MB, 1204.7 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  121097 ms: Mark-sweep 1348.1 (1404.3) -> 1362.7 (1403.3) MB, 1723.2 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].
  122416 ms: Mark-sweep 1362.7 (1403.3) -> 1377.4 (1403.3) MB, 1317.9 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0000034B7C13FA99 <JS Object>
    1: set [native collection.js:~252] [pc=00000174AF1BC2E1] (this=000003AD36FBC469 <a Map with map 0000002CF18113B1>,r=000002D7A3418CD9 <String[12]: 32741,580445>,z=1)
    2: /* anonymous */ [C:\TPO\Client\Angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:~2177] [pc=00000174ADC9EBD0] (this=000001D0EA536CE1 <JS Global Object>,value=1,key=000002D7A3418CD9 <String[12]: 32741,580445>)
    3: arg...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

Comment: Have you had a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45322901/javascript-heap-out-of-memory-in-angular-2 ? Maybe that could helps you

Comment: I love you. It worked. I wasted an entire day on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless there is something wrong with your application, the simplest way to get rid of the problem (as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43604354/8513835)) is to increase heap size for node.js

On Windows this can be done by navigating to

```
C:\Users\your_user_name\%AppData%\Roaming\npm
```

and then editing your `ng.cmd` in there:

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe" --max_old_space_size=4096 "%~dp0\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node --max_old_space_size=4096 "%~dp0\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng" %*
)
```

The `--max_old_space_size=4096` sets the heap size for node's V8 engine to corresponding value in MBs (in our case this is 4096, but probably you may fine-tune it depending on your workstation's capabilities) instead of default value of 1400 MB

Answer (score 0):

This question showed up when I was looking to solve the `Javascript heap out of memory` error while building my Next.js project.

Therefore, adding a more generic answer for those that stumble across here.

I solved the error by adding `NODE_OPTIONS='--max-old-space-size=4096'` to the `build` script in `package.json` as shown in the following example.

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "NODE_OPTIONS='--max-old-space-size=4096' next build"
  }
}
```

It increases the Node.js heap size. For me `4096` was enough but please adjust it as per your project needs.