# gulp build task throws FATAL ERROR: invalid table size Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, gulp

I'm working on website using yeoman/gulp and when I'm updating my site using gulp build, console throws and error:

```
  [01:21:52] Starting 'lint'...
  [01:21:52] Starting 'styles'...
  [01:21:52] Starting 'scripts'...
  [01:21:53] Starting 'images'...
  [01:21:53] Starting 'fonts'...
  [01:21:53] Starting 'extras'...
  [01:21:53] Finished 'lint' after 1.54 s
  [01:21:53] Finished 'styles' after 1.27 s
  [01:21:53] Finished 'scripts' after 1.19 s
  [01:21:53] Starting 'html'...

  <--- Last few GCs --->

     15261 ms: Scavenge 631.7 (667.9) -> 615.9 (667.9) MB, 0.2 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure].
     15471 ms: Scavenge 640.7 (676.9) -> 624.9 (676.9) MB, 0.3 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure].
     15657 ms: Scavenge 649.7 (685.9) -> 633.9 (685.9) MB, 0.3 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure].
     18538 ms: Mark-sweep 1107.9 (1161.2) -> 491.5 (691.8) MB, 4.9 / 0.0 ms (+ 194.3 ms in 94 steps since start of marking, biggest step 85.3 ms) [GC interrupt] [GC in old space requested].


  <--- JS stacktrace --->

  ==== JS stack trace =========================================

  Security context: 0x2ffcdcbcfb51 <JS Object>
      1: DoJoin(aka DoJoin) [native array.js:131] [pc=0x1f13fa717d37] (this=0x2ffcdcb04381 <undefined>,w=0x193e934043d9 <JS Array[17303464]>,x=17303464,N=0x2ffcdcb043c1 <true>,J=0x193e93405221 <String[8]\: ,\n      >,I=0x2ffcdcbb46e1 <JS Function ConvertToString (SharedFunctionInfo 0x2ffcdcb52dc9)>)
      2: Join(aka Join) [native array.js:180] [pc=0x1f13fa7177d2] (this=0x2ffcdcb04381 <undefined>,w...

  FATAL ERROR: invalid table size Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
   1: node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
   2: node::FatalException(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Message>) [/usr/local/bin/node]
   3: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
   4: v8::internal::Dictionary<v8::internal::SeededNumberDictionary, v8::internal::SeededNumberDictionaryShape, unsigned int>::New(v8::internal::Isolate*, int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/usr/local/bin/node]
   5: v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::FastElementsAccessor<v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::FastHoleyObjectElementsAccessor, v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::ElementsKindTraits<(v8::internal::ElementsKind)3> >::NormalizeImpl(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FixedArrayBase>) [/usr/local/bin/node]
   6: v8::internal::JSObject::NormalizeElements(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSObject>) [/usr/local/bin/node]
   7: v8::internal::Runtime_NormalizeElements(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
   8: 0x1f13fa6092a7
   9: 0x1f13fa717d37
  Abort trap: 6
  macbooks-MacBook-Pro:
```

Normaly, there is no problem like this. I'm using this often and it's the first time I see this error.

Comment: You are just running out of memory...

Comment: Ok, so what I need to do to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js heap out of memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558989/node-js-heap-out-of-memory)

Comment: Figured out? I tried `gulp build --max-old-space-size=8192` even lower space size did not work. Any help please? I am using yeoman WebApp generator with gulp.