# Webpack frozen during '91% additional asset processing'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, electron, babeljs, antd

I've recently added a great UI library called 'Antd' to my project.
https://ant.design/docs/react/introduce

It worked flawlessly in my dev environment and I've implemented a lot of components into my Electron App. Now when I come to package it for release, my Webpack is completely stuck at the '91% additional asset processing' stage and eventually V8 runs out of memory. I have no further output. Is there anywhere I can get more detailed logs to determine whats going on?

The problematic web pack config is below, its heavily based off the React Electron Boilerplate GitHub repo and its served me extremely well up until now.

```
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';
import { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } from 'webpack-bundle-analyzer';
import merge from 'webpack-merge';
import BabiliPlugin from 'babili-webpack-plugin';
import baseConfig from './webpack.config.base';

export default merge.smart(baseConfig, {
  // devtool: 'source-map',

  target: 'electron-renderer',

  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './app/index'],

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'app/dist'),
    publicPath: '../dist/'
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      // Extract all .global.css to style.css as is
      {
        test: /\.global\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          use: 'css-loader',
          fallback: 'style-loader',
        })
      },
      // Pipe other styles through css modules and append to style.css
      {
        test: /^((?!\.global).)*\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          use: {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
            }
          }
        }),
      },
      // Add SASS support  - compile all .global.scss files and pipe it to style.css
      {
        test: /\.global\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'css-loader'
            },
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader'
            }
          ],
          fallback: 'style-loader',
        })
      },
      // Add SASS support  - compile all other .scss files and pipe it to style.css
      {
        test: /^((?!\.global).)*\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          use: [{
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader'
          }]
        }),
      },
      // WOFF Font
      {
        test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 10000,
            mimetype: 'application/font-woff',
          }
        },
      },
      // WOFF2 Font
      {
        test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 10000,
            mimetype: 'application/font-woff',
          }
        }
      },
      // TTF Font
      {
        test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 10000,
            mimetype: 'application/octet-stream'
          }
        }
      },
      // EOT Font
      {
        test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: 'file-loader',
      },
      // SVG Font
      {
        test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 10000,
            mimetype: 'image/svg+xml',
          }
        }
      },
      // Common Image Formats
      {
        test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|webp)$/,
        use: 'url-loader',
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    /**
     * Create global constants which can be configured at compile time.
     *
     * Useful for allowing different behaviour between development builds and
     * release builds
     *
     * NODE_ENV should be production so that modules do not perform certain
     * development checks
     */
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production')
    }),

    /**
     * Babli is an ES6+ aware minifier based on the Babel toolchain (beta)
     */
    new BabiliPlugin(),

    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css'),

    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
      analyzerMode: process.env.OPEN_ANALYZER === 'true' ? 'server' : 'disabled',
      openAnalyzer: process.env.OPEN_ANALYZER === 'true'
    }),
  ],
});
```

And here is the stack trace from the webpack output;

```
16706ms building modules                                                                   
137ms sealing
10ms optimizing
0ms basic module optimization 
17ms module optimization
1ms advanced module optimization 
0ms basic chunk optimization 
0ms chunk optimization 
25ms advanced chunk optimization
2162ms building modules                                                                   
0ms module and chunk tree optimization 
15ms module reviving
8ms module order optimization 
7ms module id optimization 
4ms chunk reviving 
0ms chunk order optimization 
22ms chunk id optimization
55ms hashing
1ms module assets processing 
109ms chunk assets processing
4ms additional chunk assets processing 
1ms recording 
 91% additional asset processing
<--- Last few GCs --->

[1279:0x103801600]   485158 ms: Mark-sweep 1339.5 (1509.3) -> 1339.5 (1509.8) MB, 2810.3 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure GC in old space requested
[1279:0x103801600]   488159 ms: Mark-sweep 1339.5 (1509.8) -> 1339.4 (1463.3) MB, 3001.2 / 0.0 ms  last resort 
[1279:0x103801600]   491070 ms: Mark-sweep 1339.4 (1463.3) -> 1339.4 (1456.3) MB, 2910.5 / 0.0 ms  last resort 
<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x2511c21a66a1 <JS Object>
    1: set [native weak-collection.js:~43] [pc=0x2de514c759df](this=0x28fdfc5c2d29 <JS WeakMap>,m=0x267d0ab55949 <a Node with map 0x2b746f329501>,o=0x1fe36e4c1f89 <JS Array[0]>)
    2: get [/Users/alexmorris/Documents/FCA/eBundleViewer/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/index.js:~76] [pc=0x2de515031fe1](this=0x13d83be85de1 <JS Function NodePath (SharedFunctionInfo 0x7dd00c3dae1)>,_ref=0x2129c...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
```

Any help would be HUGELY appreciated! Thanks,
Alex

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558989/node-js-heap-out-of-memory/66914674#66914674

Answer (score 3):

Try setting `devtool: 'cheap'`. If you have a large app, generating sourcemaps can be expensive. Its a temporary solution until [this issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4558) fully gets gets

Also it seems like this project is based off of electron-react-boilerplate, which I am a core maintainer of. You should open bug reports/issues there.

Comment: Great suggestion, thanks! I'll try it at work tomorrow. I have just posted another question which I hope gets viewed by some smart people such as yourself.

Comment: Thanks for all the work on the boilerplate by the way. Had to get a decently sized application up and running in next to no time so its been an absolute life saver over the past couple of months.

Answer (score 0):

Below settings helped me to reduce the heap memory since it will not include the sourceMap file.

```
devtool: false, // Webpack.

new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
   sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap
}),
```

or below code will help for latest webpack uglify plugin.

```
> npm install uglifyjs-webpack-plugin --save-dev

// conf.js
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        sourceMap: true,
      }),
    ],
  },
};
```

If this still not help to fix the problem. below command helps to increase heap memory and answer link to know more about heap memory is below as well.

```
node --max-old-space-size=16000 scripts/build.js
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57480923/1533666

Answer (score 0):

Bellow's worked for me.....
I removed bootstrap (Styles and Script) links from angular.json
and also removed this lines.

```
 "cli": {
"analytics": "0261d1e0-3775-4486-8b80-807954bcb6c2"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was `ts-loader` that was responsible. I added the following option and it worked:

```js
{
  loader: 'ts-loader',
  options: {
    // ...my other options
    transpileOnly: true // <- This!
  }
}
```