# Angular Production Build is taking about 1.5 GB of memory and still runs Out Of Memory

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-cli

**Angular2 cli** Project Production Build **[ng build -prod]** getting struck on 92% and getting error message like, running out of heap memory. Is there any solution for it? 
Project consists of huge number of components.
Normal build is working fine **[ng build]**

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bowua.jpg)

Thank you

Comment: `--max_old_space_size`  https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7024

Comment: Thank you, already tried same command but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: You're doing something wrong. It should work

Comment: try with : node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js

Comment: @SandipPatel getting error : No configuration file found and no output filename configured via CLI option.
A configuration file could be named 'webpack.config.js' in the current directory.
Use --help to display the CLI options.

Comment: @yurzui : ng build -prod -aot=false this command will work, but setting flag "false" and running is not a good solution i think, because it will escape template errors

Comment: I know that `-aot=false` will work for you but try adding `--max_old_space_size` to `ng.cmd` command

Comment: @yurzui : but how to set --max_old_space_size, where i can find ng.cmd

Comment: `node_modules\.bin` folder http://take.ms/QnEdh

Comment: @yurzui : thank you.

Comment: @SandipPatel : thank you

Comment: it's sad that we have such problems with building big applications

Comment: @yurzui : that's correct, angular 2 need to find solution for it.

Answer (score 3):

There is only one workaround today.

Open `./node_modules/.bin/ng.cmd` and add `--max_old_space_size` option

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe" --max_old_space_size=8192 "%~dp0\..\@angular\cli\bin\ng" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node  --max_old_space_size=8192  "%~dp0\..\@angular\cli\bin\ng" %*
)
```

Or you can upgrade your computer:)

Related issue on github

- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5618

Comment: Thanks yurzui, but node_modules folder is dynamically creating file na? when we run npm install, setting "max_old_space_size" may work in our system, but many people work together, this cant be solve using setting memory size on each machine? is there any quick solution to add it in package.json file? so it will run and execute on all machines.

Comment: running on 8 GB RAM :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a Node Version >= 8, you can use the solution posted in [Node.js heap out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558989/node-js-heap-out-of-memory):

In your package.json file, replace `ng build xxx` with `node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build xxx`

The value 8192 is the space in MB which node and angular as well will be allowed to use

Answer (score -1):

Please check the version of Angular CLI, If its 1.2.6 downgrade it to **1.2.1**. It will work.
I too have the same issue and solved by this mean. 
*NB: it's only a temporary fix.*
Hope cli team will solve the issue ASAP.

Comment: Getting error like : ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error:                                                                      
Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'D:\projectpath\src'
 @ ./src/main.ts 3:0-74
 @ multi ./src/main.ts