# how do i parse large tsv file to json via Nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, csv, parsing

I have a file of size 370mb. Which i need to parse and then update entries in mongodb for this i have used npm node-tsv-json.It works well for small files but not for larger one.It says **FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory**

Comment: this might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558989/node-js-heap-out-of-memory

Comment: yes but how do i  change it permenantly