# NativeScript CLI installation Error

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-cli

I am trying to learn NativeScript. I have done following steps to install NativeScript on my windows 8.1 Pro 64 bit machine:

1. Installed node.js (node-v8.11.2-x64) on D drive
2. Installed Visual Studio Code (VSCodeSetup-x64-1.23.1) on D drive
3. Installed Git (Git-2.17.0-64-bit) on D drive
4. Installed Android Studio (android-studio-ide-173.4720617-windows) on D drive
5. Installed NativeScript by using following command: npm install -g nativescript.

I receive following error on step 5:

```
C:\Users\UserName>npm install -g nativescript
nativescript@4.0.1 preuninstall C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript

node preuninstall.js

Failed to complete all pre-uninstall steps.

C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\tns -> C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\bin\tns

C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\nativescript -> C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\bin\tns

> nativescript@4.0.1 postinstall C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript

> node postinstall.js

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

at normalizeStringWin32 (path.js:33:30)

at Object.resolve (path.js:328:20)

at sync (C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:68:14)

at sync (C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:77:24)

at sync (C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)

at sync (C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)

at sync (C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)

at sync (C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)

at sync (C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)

at sync (C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.3 (node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\fsevents):

    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ nativescript@4.0.1

updated 1 package in 18.244s
```

When I run tns doctor command I receive following information:

```
> C:\Users\UserName>tns doctor
> 
> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
> 
>     at normalizeStringWin32 (path.js:33:30)
> 
>     at Object.resolve (path.js:328:20)
> 
>     at sync (C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:68:14)
> 
>     at sync (C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:77:24)
> 
>     at sync (C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)
> 
>     at sync (C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)
> 
>     at sync (C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)
> 
>     at sync (C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)
> 
>     at sync (C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)
> 
>     at sync (C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)
```

I also tried to uninstall NativeScript but it gets stuck on still resolveWithNewModule, see below:

```
C:\Users\UserName>npm uninstall -g  nativescript

[  ................] / loadDep:readdirp: sill resolveWithNewModule xcode@0.8.0 checking installable status
```

My questions are:

1. How to fix installation error for NativeScript?
2. If I need to uninstall NativeScript, how can I do that?
3. Which directory NativeScript gets installed with the installed command and can I install it on d drive?

Comment: How much ram do you have on your machine?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the installation process is running out of memory.
Try running this command before running the installation:

```
node --max-old-space-size=8192
```

Set the last number according to RAM installed on your machine (2048, 4096 ecc)

Comment: I doubt it is a memory issue, I have 32GB of RAM. Anywayz I tried your suggestion but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

@Aaron Ullal is right, the reason is mostly NodeJS heap (memory usage in V8) is running out of usable memory, is not because you have no ram left, this is a hard stop included in node exec config.

you can add a flag to increase the heap size on the go

`NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=4096" node`

You can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558989/node-js-heap-out-of-memory).
Please use the search tool to find similar errors or answered questions