# How to load a large geojson file in leaflet

Tags: node.js, angular, leaflet

I am having a large Geojson file about 9mb that i need to load in angular 5 using leaflet but the application crash when i run ng serve giving this error:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[18416:0215BF30]   248777 ms: Mark-sweep 734.9 (778.9) -> 734.7 (783.9) MB, 946.3 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure GC in old space requested
[18416:0215BF30]   249725 ms: Mark-sweep 734.7 (783.9) -> 734.6 (766.9) MB, 947.1 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested
[18416:0215BF30]   250669 ms: Mark-sweep 734.6 (766.9) -> 734.6 (766.4) MB, 943.8 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 35816169 <JSObject>
    1: addMappingWithCode [C:\Users\Mhuss\Desktop\modz\programming\Angular\leaflet-geojson\node_modules\webpack-sources\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-node.js:~150] [pc=085B361A](this=04A85729 <JSGlobal Object>,mapping=1621A345 <Object map = 088F842D>,code=3816C225 <String[3]: 0.0>)
    2: /* anonymous */ [C:\Users\Mhuss\Desktop\modz\programming\Angular\leaflet-geojson\node_modules\webpack-sources...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node_module_register
 2: v8::internal::Factory::NewUninitializedFixedArray
 3: v8::internal::WasmDebugInfo::SetupForTesting
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js heap out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558989/node-js-heap-out-of-memory)