# CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: node.js

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

1: 
node::Abort()
2: 
0x10a03cc
3: 
v8::Utils::ReportApiFailure(char const*, char const*)
4: 
v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool)
5: 
v8::internal::Factory::NewTransitionArray(int)
6: 
v8::internal::TransitionArray::Insert(v8::internal::Handle, v8::internal::Handle, v8::internal::Handle, v8::internal::SimpleTransitionFlag)
7: 
v8::internal::Map::CopyReplaceDescriptors(v8::internal::Handle, v8::internal::Handle, v8::internal::Handle, v8::internal::TransitionFlag, v8::internal::MaybeHandle, char const*, v8::internal::SimpleTransitionFlag) 
8: 
v8::internal::Map::CopyAddDescriptor(v8::internal::Handle, v8::internal::Descriptor*, v8::internal::TransitionFlag) 
9: 
v8::internal::Map::CopyWithConstant(v8::internal::Handle, v8::internal::Handle, v8::internal::Handle, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes, v8::internal::TransitionFlag) 
10: 
v8::internal::Map::TransitionToDataProperty(v8::internal::Handle, v8::internal::Handle, v8::internal::Handle, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes, v8::internal::Object::StoreFromKeyed) 
11: 
v8::internal::LookupIterator::PrepareTransitionToDataProperty(v8::internal::Handle, v8::internal::Handle, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes, v8::internal::Object::StoreFromKeyed)
12: 
v8::internal::StoreIC::LookupForWrite(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle, v8::internal::Object::StoreFromKeyed) 
13: 
v8::internal::StoreIC::UpdateCaches(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle, v8::internal::Object::StoreFromKeyed) 
14: 
v8::internal::StoreIC::Store(v8::internal::Handle, v8::internal::Handle, v8::internal::Handle, v8::internal::Object::StoreFromKeyed) 
15: 
v8::internal::KeyedStoreIC::Store(v8::internal::Handle, v8::internal::Handle, v8::internal::Handle) 
16: 
v8::internal::Runtime_KeyedStoreIC_Miss(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) 
17: 0x218d5a6092a7

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558989/node-js-heap-out-of-memory/66914674#66914674

Answer (score 0):

Normally this happens when old space size of the heap is not enough to run the process due to extraordinary memory usage.

This can be fixed by increasing the old space size as below, when you start the node.js code in command line.

```
node --max-old-space-size=4096 index.js
```

Here i increased the --max-old-space-size to 4GB