Crypto.js Uncaught RangeError:Invalid array length
I need to do uploadFile, I using Crypto.js encrypt the file with MD5.
But when the file size over than 200Mb. I got this error message.

Uncaught RangeError: Invalid array length

I wondering to know how should I resolve the question? And Why do I get this error message?
This is my code:
<script>
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js'
const calculateMD5 = (file) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const fileReader = new FileReader()
    fileReader.onload = function () {
      const hash = CryptoJS.MD5(CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(fileReader.result))
      resolve(hash.toString())
    }
    fileReader.onerror = reject
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
  })
}

const splitFile = async (event: Event) => {
  const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement
  const CHUNK_SIZE = 10 * 1024 * 1024
  if (target.files && target.isDefaultNamespace.length > 0) {
    const file = target.files[0]
    const fileSize = file.size
    const md5hash = await calculateMD5(file)
    console.log(md5hash)

    const chunks = Math.ceil(fileSize / CHUNK_SIZE)
    const fileChunks = []
    let start = 0
    let end = CHUNK_SIZE
    console.log(end, fileSize)

    for (let i = 0; i < chunks; i++) {
      if (end > fileSize) {
        console.log('if', i)

        end = fileSize
      }
      const chunk = file.slice(start, end)
      console.log(chunk)

      fileChunks.push(chunk)
      start = end
      end = start + CHUNK_SIZE
    }
    console.log(fileChunks)
  }
}
</script>
<template>
 <input type="file" @change="splitFile">
</template>

The information I found shows Seems like a restriction.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55465821/getting-heap-out-of-memory-error-even-when-available-heap-memory-is-much-larger
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54452896/maximum-number-of-entries-in-node-js-map/54466812#54466812

Do you really need support for such large files? What is the use case here? Also, minor notes: Hashing and encryption are 2 different things. MD5 is unsecure and unreliable. Use SHA-256 or SHA-512.

You should incrementally hash the file to avoid using all the resources allocated to the browser. Process the file in chunks and compute the MD5 hash incrementally with a library like spark-md5
import SparkMD5 from 'spark-md5';

const calculateMD5 = (file) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const CHUNK_SIZE = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // Chunk size: 10MB
    const spark = new SparkMD5.ArrayBuffer();
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    let currentChunk = 0;
    const chunks = Math.ceil(file.size / CHUNK_SIZE);

    fileReader.onload = function(e) {
      spark.append(e.target.result); // Append chunk to the hash
      currentChunk++;
      if (currentChunk < chunks) {
        loadNext();
      } else {
        resolve(spark.end()); // Compute final hash
      }
    };

    fileReader.onerror = () => reject('Error reading file');

    const loadNext = () => {
      const start = currentChunk * CHUNK_SIZE;
      const end = Math.min(start + CHUNK_SIZE, file.size);
      fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file.slice(start, end));
    };

    loadNext();
  });
};

Using spark-md5 for incremental hashing, reduces memory usage and prevents the "heap out of memory" error for large files by never loading the entire file into memory at once
