# FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory in Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-serve

When I run an Ionic 3 project using the `ionic serve` command, then I am getting this error:

[image: Screenshot of FATAL ERROR: ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript]

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558989/node-js-heap-out-of-memory/66914674#66914674

Answer (score 714):

For a non-Angular general answer for those who land on this question from Google:

Most times when you face this error it’s probably because of a memory leak, an addition/version upgrade of a library or a difference in how Node.js manages memory between versions (e.g. Node.js version <=  10 and Node.js version > 10).

Usually just increasing the memory allocated to Node.js will allow your program to run *but may not actually solve the real problem* and the memory used by the node process could still exceed the new memory you allocate. I'd advise profiling memory usage in your Node.js process when it starts running or updating to Node.js > 10.

I had a memory leak.
Here is [a great article](https://www.toptal.com/nodejs/debugging-memory-leaks-node-js-applications) on debugging memory leaks in Node.js.

That said, to increase the memory, in the terminal where you run your Node.js process:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"
```

Or for Windows:

```
Set NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"
```

where values of `max-old-space-size` can be: `[2048, 4096, 8192, 16384]` etc

More examples for further clarity:

```bash
export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=5120" # Increase to 5 GB
export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=6144" # Increase to 6 GB
export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=7168" # Increase to 7 GB
export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192" # Increase to 8 GB

# and so on...

# formula:
export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=(X * 1024)" # Increase to X GB

# Note: it doesn't have to be multiples of 1024.
# max-old-space-size can be any number of memory megabytes (MB) you have available.
```

### See the current value of max-old-space-size (in MB)

To see the current (not exact but very close) value of max-old-space-size (in MB), run in your terminal

```bash
node -e 'console.log(v8.getHeapStatistics().heap_size_limit/(1024*1024))'
```

Comment: FYI, the default is 512 MB. You don't need to jump straight to 10x that amount, you could try something between 512 and 5120 first.

Comment: Thanks this works for all types of application having memory issues.

Comment: Just want to point out - thats its not always indicative of a memory leak. Perhaps a library you are using is using a bit more memory than it used to. For us `next.js` began crashing our app with the fast refresh feature.

Comment: @DanielCooke what value you used for next js? can you please share what solution you used for this issue with next js

Comment: @MSD We seem to get by with 4096 max-old-space-size with next > 9.6. For production builds and dev

Comment: @DanielCooke thanks ... tried that not working for me

Comment: Here are the docs https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_max_old_space_size_size_in_megabytes and nothing suggests that there should be steps of `integer * 1024`.

Comment: @MikhailVasin See the very last comments in my answer. I know it doesn't. I just put that there for those that want the common memory increments in GB.

Comment: Is it just window thing? In windows, I had to use "max_old_space_size" instead of "max-old-space-size" (so use an underscore instead of a dash).

Comment: During export 2.5 Lakh record in Excel Sheet.
I have faced same issue.
After run below command
export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=5120"
my issue is Resolved.

Comment: Just FYI on node 18 it defaults to 4144

Comment: Just my 2 cents, guys, you should take into account that artice describes the case in vitro. In the real life projects it's nearly to impossible to give a name to all anonymous functions and you have a ton of node_modules with anonymous callbacks. I have had a 2Gb leak inside a PM2 process, but when I made a heap snapshot it was about 30Mb. No matter how much memory the process used to consume I didn't catch anything more than 30Mb. What else? Happy js debugging, colleagues!

Answer (score 105):

In my case, I fixed this problem by installing Node.js, version 12.10.0.

Comment: Same here. I've just changed the version and its works.

Comment: For context, Node 12 has a different heap management strategy which is based on available memory instead of using defaults. More details here: https://foundation.nodejs.org/announcements/2019/04/24/node-js-foundation-and-js-foundation-merge-to-form-openjs-foundation-2

Comment: Nothing else worked for me, this was it. Thank you so much :)

Comment: We updated to Node 12 and the error went away, easier than managing heap on Node 10

Comment: This fixed the issue. It should be accepted as the answer

Comment: @NitishKumar I'm still receiving the error with Node 12 /shrug. The accepted should be whichever best solves the OP's use case -- though you'd've hoped they would have selected one of the answers at this point.

Comment: this one only worked for me but in angular project.

Comment: @DerekDowling Wayback cause link broken: https://web.archive.org/web/20191103115941/https://foundation.nodejs.org/announcements/2019/04/24/node-js-foundation-and-js-foundation-merge-to-form-openjs-foundation-2

Comment: I am using node 12.18.3 and got this error.

Comment: I was using node 11.15.0, while making build got "Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory", After updating to node 12.10.0(nvm install 12.10.0) everything works like a charm!!!

Answer (score 97):

Just type this in the terminal:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"
```

The error occurs when you exceed the default maximum memory allowed for Node.js. All this does is increase the maximum memory allowed.

Comment: This is the solution if you are working on the shell

Comment: @Matt can you add to your solution, how to see the existing value for "--max-old-space-size" before we actually tweak it?

Comment: This should be accepted as the right answer. Thanks for sharing it.

Answer (score 90):

I had the same issue on [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) server 7, but this solved my problem:

```
node --max-old-space-size=X node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod
```

Where `X = (2048 or 4096 or 8192 o..)` is the value of memory.

Comment: after changing the value of x.. error remains the same

Comment: If the error continues, keep increasing the size until there is enough memory to process which will eventually prevent the error. The only time I found I couldn't get past this error was with `ng serve` and a _massive_ .js file referenced in the `scripts` section of `angular.json` that needed to be loaded into memory.

Comment: can I set the value of X greater than 8192? I have 32GB of RAM

Comment: for me, supplying max-old-space-size on the command line did NOT work.  This MAY be an interaction with nvm based node?  instead inside a bash script, i used 'NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=2048" node $NG build --prod --progress=false' which worked, as opposed to 'node --max-old-space-size=2048 $NG build --prod --progress=false' which did not.  I still don not know why.

Comment: if you run this inside docker and get KILLED error, increase the RAM allocated to docker engine as well.

Answer (score 64):

I got the same error when I execute `ng build` command in Visual Studio Code. But I can build successfully when I execute the same thing on the Windows command line in the following sequence.

Step 1.

```
set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096
```

Step 2.

```
ng build
```

Comment: Thanks that helped me a lot, just switched my terminal

Comment: I have added it to file bath `/Users/MY_USER/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm.cmd`
it works fine

Comment: This work for me on GIT Bash.

Answer (score 50):

**Windows**

From the control panel go to *System* → *Advanced system settings* → *Environment Variables* → *New* (user or system)

[image: mceclip0.png]

Or this can be done in PowerShell with:

```
$env:NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"
```

You can also increase this number, if necessary. We've seen folks need to increase this up to 14 GB for some larger projects!

**Linux/macOS**

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192
```

Comment: I have nodeJS 10.15.3, i tried the NODE-OPTIONS solution on Windows 10 but it didn't work. Is there any other solutions ?

Comment: @VenomBerry could you run WSL? Why hurt yourself by running this stuff on standard windows without a linux subsystem.

Comment: It looks like now we have to use `max-old-space-size=8192` without leading dashes in the System Settings. With `--` I got `Fatal javascript OOM in GC during deserialization` error in Node.js. But probably it is related to the latest versions only.

Comment: @it3xl with newer node versions you still need to use -- or it won't be read as a change. The issue you are experiencing is that (at least some) newer versions of node node actually adds 24 bytes to the number you ask for, so asking for 4096MB turns into 4294967320 bytes,  or 4096.00002MB which node can't deserialize... Try 4000

Comment: How can we see what that value is before we tweak it??

Comment: This worked for me. Needed to also restart Visual Studio Code.

Comment: I have to try with underscore as hyphen didn't worked in `Variable Value`. `--max_old_space_size=8192`

Answer (score 43):

Try this solution which was pointed out in an old message on the forum: *[3.7.0: iOS build with --prod not working](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/3-7-0-ios-build-with-prod-not-working/107061/24)*

Open `node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/bin/ionic-app-scripts.js`

Change the first line from:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/env node --max-old-space-size=4096
```

Try values 1024 and 2048, but for a relatively large app you may need 4096.

Comment: You should not change the scripts inside node_modules.

Comment: This is a patch, temporary solution

Answer (score 23):

In my case it was a **recursion** that was causing React to use up all memory.

This happened when I was refactoring my code and didn't notice this.

```
const SumComponent = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <SumComponent />
    </>
  )
}
```

In other Node.js applications this might look like:

```
const someFunction = () => {
  ...
  someFunction();
  ...
}
```

Comment: Why was this a problem? <></> should be valid in React instead of using <React.Fragment> right?

Comment: @Codehiker Yep its a new syntax in React 16

Comment: The recursion is that `SumComponent` contains a `SumComponent` (which contains a `SumComponent` which contains a `SumComponent`... )

Answer (score 16):

I got the same error message when I executed the following statements in Visual Studio Code. But I can build successfully when I execute the same thing in on the Windows command line.

```
npm install -g increase-memory-limit
increase-memory-limit
set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096
ng build -c deploy --build-optimizer --aot --prod --sourceMap
```

Comment: directly setting --max_old_space_size=4096 in npm script or as node_options wasnt working for me it started working after installing what you stated. THANK YOU!!!!!

Answer (score 15):

Updating from Node.js 12 to Node.js 14 solved the problem for me.

---

**Update** 
Now Node.js 16 is available, and I recommend updating to the latest available version of Node.js.

Comment: Yep, using `16.4.2` with Angular 11 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 11):

1. export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=6144" #it will increase to 6gb.

-------If Not Solved try this 2nd step-------------
2) Just update your node version to the latest one will solve this issue.

-------If Not Solved try this 3rd step-------------
3)Just run this command in your windows terminal.
`set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096`

Answer (score 9):

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --baseHref=/baseUrl/ --prod=true
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 9):

For some reasons all the previous answers didn't really work for me. I did the following to fix my issue:

1. I had to first delete the `node_modules` folder
2. reinstall Node.js on my PC and
3. then `npm install`

Comment: step 2 is not mandatory. I tried upper solution and it worked for me without step 2 as well

Comment: well you may not need step 2, i only shared what worked for me :)

Answer (score 9):

Adding parameter `--build-optimizer` resolved the issue in my case:

`node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --build-optimizer`

I am not sure why adding only --build-optimizer solves the issue, but as per the Angular documentation it should be used with ahead-of-time (AOT) compilation enabled, so the updated command should be like below:

```
--build-optimizer=true --aot=true
```

[Angular build documentation](https://angular.io/cli/build)

Answer (score 9):

For me, I had a syntax error (which didn't show up) and caused this error.

Comment: In my case it is forgot to remove a comma at the end of ngClass. Hope it could help someone.

Comment: Oh god, I have something like `import { async } from '../../../../public/js/app'` in my code for some reason. You just saved me some good hours!

Answer (score 8):

Replace the line

`"start": "ng serve -o --port 4300 --configuration=en"` with

`"start": "node --max_old_space_size=5096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve -o --port 4300 --configuration=en"`

NOTE:

1. port--4300 is not constant depends upon which port you selects.
2. --max_old_space_size=5096 too not constant; any value 1024,2048,4096 etc

Comment: This one worked for me. Setting the `NODE_OPTIONS` from the command line didn't work, I'm guessing because Visual Studio uses a new process or something. Hard coding the change into my package.json `scripts` block solved it.

Answer (score 6):

Run this command in your project folder. Use **serve** instead of build

```
node --max_old_space_size=8000 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve  --prod --port=4202
```

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same problem on Angular. Then I wrote

```
"serve": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve"
```

this script to `package.json` scripts and for me this problem solved.

And run project this command:

```
npm run serve
```

Comment: This is close to incomprehensible. Can you fix it?

Comment: First of all you must add the script to the scripts block into the package.json after all you must run the project with this command: `npm run serve` - @PeterSmith

Answer (score 6):

Run this command:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=2048"
```

To check how much you have already:

```
> node
> v8.getHeapStatistics()
{
  total_heap_size: 6049792,
  total_heap_size_executable: 524288,
  total_physical_size: 5477720,
  total_available_size: 1094444024,
  used_heap_size: 4141728,
  heap_size_limit: 1098907648,
  malloced_memory: 8192,
  peak_malloced_memory: 582752,
  does_zap_garbage: 0,
  number_of_native_contexts: 2,
  number_of_detached_contexts: 0
}
```

and then `heap_size_limit: 1098907648`

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using `ng build`, I have executed below command in terminal to fix this issue.

```
 node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod
```

Then do `ng serve`.

This is how my terminal look like

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS D:\ProjectPath\Project1> node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod
```

Comment: `--prod` is now deprecated, use `--configuration production` instead

Answer (score 4):

For me it was a problem with a Firebase package.

Only add "@firebase/database": "0.2.1" for your *package.json* file. Reinstall *node_modules* and it works.

Comment: *[a](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Dax90QyXgI&t=17m54s) Firebase package* or *the Firebase package*?

Answer (score 3):

I deleted the existing Node.js module and ran the below commands to fix my issue:

```
npm install -all
npm audit fix
```

Answer (score 3):

For me, the issue was having an extra `node_modules` folder that I renamed to `node_modules_old` and running an `npm install` to generate a fresh `node_modules`. Somehow the build must have still been picking up the `node_modules_old` folder, so I moved `node_modules_old` out of the directory to fix the issue.

Comment: This was my issue.  Had a `node_modules.old` folder when testing a different set of packages earlier.

Answer (score 3):

Happened to me after Upgrading react and react-native libraries.
Solved by:

```
rm -rf node_modules **/node_modules && rm -rf yarn.lock **/yarn.lock && yarn cache clean && yarn install
```

Comment: For me running yarn cache clean did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Please check your Node.js version:

```js
   node -v
```

If it’s 10.1.1 something, then you need to update your root level Node.js version via the below commands:

```js
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash

source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh

nvm ls

nvm install 12.18.1
```

Once done, please restart your terminal or Visual Studio.

It's working 100$.

For Ionic users, please add the below code in your package.json

[image: For Ionic user]

```js
 "ionic:build": "node --max-old-space-size=16384 ./node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/bin/ionic-app-scripts.js build",
```

Comment: actually this works if your building web through `app-scripts`, but if you build android or script like `ionic cordova build android` how?

Answer (score 2):

Another non-Angular answer (I was facing the same issue building a React application on AWS Amplify).

As mentioned by Emmanuel, it seems that it comes from the difference in the way memory is handled by Node.js v10 vs. Node.js v12.

I tried to increase memory with no avail. But using Node.js v12 did it.

Check how you can add `nvm use $VERSION_NODE_12` to your build settings [as explained by richard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56453511)

> ```
> frontend:
>   phases:
>     preBuild:
>       commands:
>         - nvm use $VERSION_NODE_12
>         - npm ci
>     build:
>       commands:
>         - nvm use $VERSION_NODE_12
>         - node -v
>         - npm run-script build
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Just run this command:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess there are plenty of ways to reach this error!

On my side, I had a loop in my `package.json`. Project A had a dependency on project B, that had a dependency on project A.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing on Windows and running into this issue while publishing, upgrade Node.js through [the official site](https://nodejs.org/en/download/).

The memory usage handling does increase with each newer version of Node.js, although I did not find exact numbers on what the increase is.

That was the only solution that worked for me. It took a whole weekend and more for me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the latest stable version of Node.js v-14.17. I was having the same issue with new Angular Ionic projects and tried most of the previous answers without success.

Finally after upgrading to Node.js 16.4.2 LTS, it fixed this issue.

Comment: Azure devops - After upgrading the task of node.js version from 10 to 12, it has resolved the pipeline error.

Answer (score 0):

Check your folder name. If your folder name has spaces, these kind of issues will be generated. Rename without spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If this happening on running a React application in Visual Studio Code, please check your propTypes, undefined Proptypes leads to the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me I got this error because I lost access to the output path for the dist folder set in my angular.json file. After I reconnected to the remote path with updated credentials the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

`#!/usr/bin/env node --max-old-space-size=4096` in the *ionic-app-scripts.js* file didn’t work.

Modifying *node_modules/.bin/ionic-app-scripts.cmd* by adding

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\..\@ionic\app-scripts\bin\ionic-app-scripts.js" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node --max_old_space_size=4096  "%~dp0\..\@ionic\app-scripts\bin\ionic-app-scripts.js" %*
)
```

finally worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I encountered this problem when running [ESLint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESLint) and [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) with a large `build` directory in my React project. After removing it, all things worked.

I guess this is because there are too many files in the `build` directory.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was gone after I've updated my all libraries like, Node.js, TypeScript, [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/), npm, etc. for my project.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue when I run angular 'ng serve':

> "FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory"

In my case I found my Angular application used lazy loading. One module was already imported to itself route module, but someone made an importing it to app module too which caused the recursive(?) loading.

This causes the out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

For a non-Angular general JavaScript answer for those who land on this question from Google and want to fix this in your `Dockerfile` (replace `6144` with the amount of memory in megabytes which you want to allocate).

My implementation was working in Node.js v14.1.0 being executed by Docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88 using [`DockerOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-docker/stable/_api/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker/index.html#module-airflow.providers.docker.operators.docker) in [airflow v2.0.1](https://airflow.apache.org/)).

```
FROM node:14.1.0

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /tmp/dockerspace/

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

CMD node --max-old-space-size=6144 app.js
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was caused by improper use of a condition in a `for ...` loop. Instead of:

```
for (let t = startNo; t <= endNo; t++) {}
```

I had:

```
for (let t = startNo; endNo; t++) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in my case after of install aws-sdk, not the memory space. I resolved it changing the import to require like this post:

[aws-sdk in node app after deploying does not start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64135036/aws-sdk-in-node-app-after-deploying-does-not-start)

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was as silly as module importing itself:

```
// worker.js
import { worker } from './worker'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the event this is useful for someone. make sure there is not recursion in our Sass. or non exiting recursion in your recently added code. in some cases max heap exceeded is a sign of this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall node.js. then download again a fresh copy to install.

Answer (score 0):

My problem got solved by using default name in import statement for @mui/icons-material. Dont know how its related to out of memory issue, but now I am  running my nextJS project smoothly after this change
example,
instead of
import { Check } from '@mui/icons-material';

I used following format

import CheckIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Check';

Answer (score 0):

For me, running

```
yarn cache clean
```

and

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

fixed the memory issue. After this

```
yarn install
```

worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

**My solution was not to increase heap size, rather restart port while it's down automatically**.
.

In my case I was running microfront architechture end with 2 Webpack services running concurrently.

Most of the times my consumer app crashes with below error

```
<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

I don't want to increase the heap size of my node server.
What I did was listen to the server port and if the port is crashed restart again by watch script in shell script

```bash
# check whether port 3009 is open for every 30 seconds, This is to automatically restart dev server when it is down due to HEAP allocation overflow


while true
do
    if lsof -Pi :3009 -sTCP:LISTEN -t >/dev/null ; then
        echo "Port 3009 is open"
    else
        echo "Port 3009 is closed"
        echo "Restarting server"
        yarn start
    fi
    sleep 30
done
``
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Error Message
# FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

his command work for me

```
# - In window 11 and Angular 17
 node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve
```

Answer (score -10):

Sometimes simplicity is the key to success. Search for `while (i <= 10000) {}` without increasing `i` in your code ;)