# How to update AWS Amplify Console's CICD DockerFile w.r.t. FrameWork Versions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm following steps mentioned in : https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-react-app-amplify-graphql/module-three/?e=gs2020&p=build-a-react-app-two

In Step3 , in the "Deploy changes to live environment" ; AWS Amplify is provisioning build environment with a Docker image :
AWS Amplify -> Provisioning -> Framework Versions
ENV VERSION_NODE_8=8.12.0
ENV VERSION_NODE_10=10.16.0
ENV VERSION_NODE_12=12
ENV VERSION_NODE_DEFAULT=$VERSION_NODE_10

How can i update ENV VERSION_NODE_DEFAULT=$ENV VERSION_NODE_12 ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException; Request ID: 77f4c020-aeea-458f-85c8-86df0160e852;

Comment: [INFO]: CREATE_FAILED          UpdateRolesWithIDPFunction     AWS::Lambda::Function  The runtime parameter of nodejs8.10 is no longer supported for creating or updating AWS Lambda functions. We recommend you use the new runtime (nodejs12.x) while creating or updating functions. (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException; Request ID: 77f4c020-aeea-458f-85c8-86df0160e852; Proxy: null)
UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS notesapp-master-20201116125403 AWS::CloudFormation::Stack The following resource(s) failed to create: [UpdateRolesWithIDPFunction]

Comment: Following resources failed
               Resource Name: UpdateRolesWithIDPFunction (AWS::Lambda::Function)
                                 Event Type: create
                                 Reason: The runtime parameter of nodejs8.10 is no longer supported for creating or updating AWS Lambda functions. We recommend you use the new runtime (nodejs12.x) while creating or updating functions. (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException; Request ID: 1a755105-752a-4d83-a3a7-846bea5944cd; Proxy: null)
[INFO]: init failed

Comment: The default node version probably cannot be changed. Here is described how to use other node versions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56453511/13017141

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With latest version of CLI it's working without any issues.

- aws-amplify/cli@4.41.0
- aws-amplify/ui-react@0.2.33
- aws-amplify@3.3.13