# Package not accessible from esbuild - What does this error mean?

Tags: node.js, npm, esbuild

While updating dependencies, I'm getting the following error:

```bash
npm ERR! esbuild-android-64 not accessible from esbuild
```

I cannot find any reference to it, apart from [a single issue](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/2202) on ESBuild that is apparently resolved by updating to Node 16, which I am already on.

I can't find what the error is trying to convey, let alone how to fix it. Has anyone ever seen a "not accessible from" error on NPM?

I'm not getting it on Mac, but our CI server is Windows and seems to encounter it regularly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to changing the node version, you can also mark the dependency as optional, as described in this [bug report](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/2202#issuecomment-1228299578):

Run:
`npm i esbuild-android-64 --save-optional`

This will result in the following in your `package.json`:

```
"optionalDependencies": {
    "esbuild-android-64": "^0.15.18",
}
```

Marking the specific package as optional tells npm it can safely ignore the install fail and continue with the other dependencies.

Answer (score 7):

Changing the Node version on AWS to match the Node version I was using on my local machine helped me to overcome this issue.

AWS was using Node v14. The issue went away when I specified Node v16.

Checkout this thread if you're deploying on AWS:
[How To Change Node Version AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56444337/how-to-change-node-version-in-provision-step-in-amplify-console)