# Error when deploying a NextJs app in Amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, next.js13

I'm trying to deploy my NextJs app in AWS Amplify without success.

My package.json as follows:

```
{
  "name": "bytecho",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@next/font": "^14.0.1",
    "next": "14.0.1",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

My amplify.yml:

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - next build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

However, when it was building, I got the following error:

[image]

Does anyone know what can be done to fix this?

Comment: Your issue is probably node/next version related. Your installing next.js14(question is tagged v13?) and line 7...8 its complaining you need at least node `18.17.0` but `16.19.0` is installed. Theres few options for updating Amplify node version - take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56444337/how-to-change-node-version-in-provision-step-in-amplify-console

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to the 2023 servers (in advanced under build settings) instead of the linux2 servers; it should be easier with your node version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I did deploy on the 2023 servers as well as the Linux2 servers.

Answer (score 0):

It says you need higher version nodejs in aws.

To achive this you need use custom image called amplify:al2023.

In advanced settings add custom image.

image name: amplify:al2023

[exmaple image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ce2O.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).