# is it normal for an ORM to run out of memory when fetching 14737 rows

Tags: javascript, postgresql, orm

I am currently using TypeORM (JavaScript) for my database interaction and have run into a problem. I am running a query that returns 14737 rows and would like to interact with those results. However, when executing this query I am getting the following error:

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

**Is it normal for an ORM to run out of memory with such a number of rows?** my computer has 16GB of ram, which I'd expect to be more than enough for this task.

Comment: It might be a node issue. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53230823/fatal-error-ineffective-mark-compacts-near-heap-limit-allocation-failed-javas

Comment: @PrerakSola I have tried that but the error persists.