# Aws - build failed with oom javascript

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I have a react project with codebuild service to deploy automatically to my S3 bucket after adding some libs I surprised with failed on build

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory 
 1: node::Abort() [node]
```

any hint why this happen

Comment: Can you try changing from BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL to BUILD_GENERAL1_LARGE compute type.

Comment: yes this do the trick Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this issue fixed by change the compute type to a larger one
Thanks for shariqmaws

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by increasing the heap before building the project

```
export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=6144" # increased to 6Gb
```

Reference: [FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory in Ionic 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53230823/fatal-error-ineffective-mark-compacts-near-heap-limit-allocation-failed-javas)