# Getting some error while running Node applications on Ubuntu-18.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-18.04

I am getting the following error while running any node applications on my machine.

> Error::

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Writing Node.js report to file: report.20200217.131017.8875.0.001.json
Node.js report completed
 1: 0xa9d570 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0xa9f832 node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]
 3: 0xc0772e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
```

Here When I am running my `node server` after sometime its throwing this error. I follow some solutions and everywhere it has written to upgrade the node version so that this error will be stopped but after upgrading the node version I am also getting the same issue. Here I need to resolve this issue.

Comment: Try search some info about **--max_old_space_size** and increase it as appropriate

Comment: possible duplicate: [FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory in ionic 3
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53230823/fatal-error-ineffective-mark-compacts-near-heap-limit-allocation-failed-javas)

Comment: @Molda: Where I will get `--max_old_space_size` from my system     ?

Comment: Somewhere in your code, you are using heavy callback or maybe within a loop.Can you please check your code properly. I think there is heavy nested unresolved callback executing from the application which is need to be fixed.