# Angular 8 error: '"node --max-old-space-size=10240"' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, angular, angular8

First I had the issue with limit allocation and I tried to resolve that using this answers here:

[FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory in ionic 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53230823/fatal-error-ineffective-mark-compacts-near-heap-limit-allocation-failed-javas)

But after that, I have this issue:

[image]

I didn't type this number 10240... I don't know where is this number from and how to solve the problem. Any idea?

Comment: Do you mean 1024?

Comment: No, see this picture, it is very strange, it is 10240...

Comment: Please try the following: 1024 or 2048 or 4096 or 8192...etc and take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53230823/fatal-error-ineffective-mark-compacts-near-heap-limit-allocation-failed-javas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally, I deleted the existing node module folder from my project and run the below commands:

```
npm install -all
npm audit fix
```

Comment: it solves the issue but after a single run I get this error again. know why?

Comment: it was issue in file `node_modules\.bin\node-sass.cmd` it contains command `node --max-old-space-size=4096` . After reinstalling npm modules cmd file does not contain this command anymore and issue is gone

Comment: in file` node_modules\.bin\node-sass.cmd` "%_prog%"  "%dp0%\..\node --max-old-space-size=4096-sass\bin\node-sass" %* - becomes to `"%_prog%"  "%dp0%\..\node --max-old-space-size=4096 -sass\bin\node-sass" %*` - adding space between `4096 -sass` - it caused issue in my case

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is still having this issue: the solution for me was to run a script via node once, which converts all "%prog%" into %prog% in each cmd file in node-modules like [this one](https://chowdera.com/2021/09/20210906195437974s.html)