# Getting an error while starting react application (npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm-start

I am getting an error while starting application on server. How to solve it. Please help me.

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffictive mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
1: 00007FF64C4FDD8A v8::internal::GCIDleTimeHandler+4506
2: 00007FF64C4D8886 node::MakeCallback+4534
3: 00007FF64C4D9200 node_module_register+2032


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 134
npm ERR! material-dashboard-react@1.9.0 start: 'react-scripts start'
npm ERR! Exit status 134
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the material-dashboard-react@1.9.0 start scripts.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020_11_40_020Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Images of text should either be augmented by the text they contain or replaced by the text they contain as those images are not searchable, accessible, and do not allow those trying to help you to copy and paste the code or messages they contain.

Comment: @JasonAller FWIW, the edit that you approved, really shouldn't have been approved. If an edit doesn't bring a closable question into an openable state it's generally better to just reject and leave it to OP to bring the question up to the required standards: see [Should I approve edits to off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267093/should-i-approve-edits-to-off-topic-questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you face this error its probably because of a memory leak or difference between how `Node` <= 10 and `Node` > 10 manage memory.

Seems like you are trying to run a ReactJS project which is implemented to match with `Node` version > `10`.

So, please **upgrade** your `Node` to the **latest version** and try.

1. Uninstall your existing Node version.
2. Install the Latest version of Node.
3. Delete `node_modules` folder of your ReactJS project.
4. Run `npm install`.
5. Run `npm start`.

You will fix the issue.

If you want to read more about this issue, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53230823/fatal-error-ineffective-mark-compacts-near-heap-limit-allocation-failed-javas) question on `Stackoverflow`.