# Node process inside docker has limited memory - way below available

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, docker-compose

I have a node app built inside docker. When I try to compile it inside the container, it runs out of memory. I run `docker-compose run api npm run build` and I get:

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
server |
server | Writing Node.js report to file: report.20200915.155423.48.0.001.json
server | <--- Last few GCs --->
server |
server | [48:0x557b183d4d20]     7413 ms: Scavenge 252.0 (254.4) -> 251.7 (254.9) MB, 1.9 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.336, current mu = 0.325) allocation failure
server | [48:0x557b183d4d20]     7416 ms: Scavenge 252.4 (254.9) -> 251.9 (255.4) MB, 1.3 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.336, current mu = 0.325) allocation failure
server | [48:0x557b183d4d20]     7425 ms: Scavenge 252.7 (255.4) -> 252.1 (256.4) MB, 7.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.336, current mu = 0.325) allocation failure
server |
server |
server | <--- JS stacktrace --->
server |
server | ==== JS stack trace =========================================
server |
server |     0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x557b16d8e2e2]
server |     1: StubFrame [pc: 0x557b16d1dfa7]
server | Security context: 0x348fb7f9a299 <JSObject>
server |     2: createNodeArray(aka createNodeArray) [0xed8f52fff49] [/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:~15644] [pc=0x1e5b159af9a1](this=0x0138ef5004d1 <undefined>,0x2eff39aac181 <JSArray[1]>,82415,0x0138ef5004d1 <undefined>)
server |     3: parseStatement(aka parseStatement) [0x34818d601ef9] [/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js...
```

Memory allocated to docker is 12GB, I can confirm this with `docker stats`:

```
2aeda754d6f8        graphql-services_api_run_30766f61adf8   0.00%               2.734MiB / 11.7GiB   0.02%               726B / 0B           0B / 0B             1
```

The process blows up when it approaches just 500mb, which is typical memory usage for typescript compilation:

```
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   0.08%               444KiB / 11.7GiB     0.00%               746B / 0B           0B / 0B             1
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   52.33%              28.81MiB / 11.7GiB   0.24%               746B / 0B           0B / 0B             19
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   52.33%              28.81MiB / 11.7GiB   0.24%               746B / 0B           0B / 0B             19
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   142.23%             118.7MiB / 11.7GiB   0.99%               746B / 0B           0B / 0B             30
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   142.23%             118.7MiB / 11.7GiB   0.99%               746B / 0B           0B / 0B             30
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   158.09%             228.6MiB / 11.7GiB   1.91%               746B / 0B           0B / 0B             30
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   158.09%             228.6MiB / 11.7GiB   1.91%               746B / 0B           0B / 0B             30
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   234.13%             337.4MiB / 11.7GiB   2.82%               746B / 0B           0B / 0B             30
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   234.13%             337.4MiB / 11.7GiB   2.82%               746B / 0B           0B / 0B             30
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   209.31%             348.4MiB / 11.7GiB   2.91%               746B / 0B           0B / 0B             30
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   209.31%             348.4MiB / 11.7GiB   2.91%               746B / 0B           0B / 0B             30
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   24.58%              3.992MiB / 11.7GiB   0.03%               746B / 0B           0B / 0B             1
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   24.58%              3.992MiB / 11.7GiB   0.03%               746B / 0B           0B / 0B             1
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   0.00%               3.828MiB / 11.7GiB   0.03%               746B / 0B           0B / 0B             1
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   0.00%               3.828MiB / 11.7GiB   0.03%               746B / 0B           0B / 0B             1
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   0.00%               3.527MiB / 11.7GiB   0.03%               746B / 0B           0B / 0B             1
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   0.00%               3.527MiB / 11.7GiB   0.03%               746B / 0B           0B / 0B             1
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   0.00%               3.504MiB / 11.7GiB   0.03%               746B / 0B           0B / 0B             1
```

I've noticed that CPU usage blows up, but not memory?

I've done a tone of looking around, but in all the cases I've found the memory available to docker was limited and the suggestion was to increase it or specify `NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size` like here [FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory in ionic 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53230823/fatal-error-ineffective-mark-compacts-near-heap-limit-allocation-failed-javas).

Specifying `NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=512"`does the trick, but I don't understand why I need to do it. I'm running node 12.13 which has dynamic heap allocation. For memory ~ 12GB the heap size [should be well over the required 512.](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/28202). If I build it this way, it never goes over 5% ~ 600MB of available memory:

```
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   0.04%               2.344MiB / 11.7GiB   0.02%               956B / 0B           0B / 0B             1
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   0.04%               2.344MiB / 11.7GiB   0.02%               956B / 0B           0B / 0B             1
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   18.79%              19.18MiB / 11.7GiB   0.16%               956B / 0B           0B / 0B             12
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   18.79%              19.18MiB / 11.7GiB   0.16%               956B / 0B           0B / 0B             12
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   116.90%             84.32MiB / 11.7GiB   0.70%               956B / 0B           0B / 0B             30
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   116.90%             84.32MiB / 11.7GiB   0.70%               956B / 0B           0B / 0B             30
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   176.67%             188.2MiB / 11.7GiB   1.57%               956B / 0B           0B / 0B             30
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   176.67%             188.2MiB / 11.7GiB   1.57%               956B / 0B           0B / 0B             30
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   150.59%             329.9MiB / 11.7GiB   2.75%               956B / 0B           0B / 0B             30
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   150.59%             329.9MiB / 11.7GiB   2.75%               956B / 0B           0B / 0B             30
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   146.39%             417.2MiB / 11.7GiB   3.48%               956B / 0B           0B / 0B             30
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   146.39%             417.2MiB / 11.7GiB   3.48%               956B / 0B           0B / 0B             30
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   207.50%             507.9MiB / 11.7GiB   4.24%               956B / 0B           0B / 0B             30
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   207.50%             507.9MiB / 11.7GiB   4.24%               956B / 0B           0B / 0B             30
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   193.23%             567.1MiB / 11.7GiB   4.73%               956B / 0B           0B / 0B             30
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   193.23%             567.1MiB / 11.7GiB   4.73%               956B / 0B           0B / 0B             30
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   220.27%             567.6MiB / 11.7GiB   4.74%               956B / 0B           0B / 0B             30
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   220.27%             567.6MiB / 11.7GiB   4.74%               956B / 0B           0B / 0B             30
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   234.85%             598.1MiB / 11.7GiB   4.99%               956B / 0B           0B / 0B             30
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   234.85%             598.1MiB / 11.7GiB   4.99%               956B / 0B           0B / 0B             30
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   218.03%             4.875MiB / 11.7GiB   0.04%               956B / 0B           0B / 0B             1
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   218.03%             4.875MiB / 11.7GiB   0.04%               956B / 0B           0B / 0B             1
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   0.00%               4.77MiB / 11.7GiB    0.04%               956B / 0B           0B / 0B             1
cab79aa591a3        graphql-services_api_run_97f2b8f5c605   0.00%               4.77MiB / 11.7GiB    0.04%               956B / 0B           0B / 0B             1
```

More over, if I just do `docker-compose build`, it seems to work just find even though my docker file also does `npm run build`. This leads me to believe that the issue with `docker-compose run`? Any pointers would be really helpful. My dockerfiles are below.

```
Dockerfile

# Base is just light node config with common tools to building
# for building npm packages
FROM mhart/alpine-node:12.18.3 AS base

RUN apk add --no-cache gcc python perl-utils g++ make perl-dev tzdata openssh git curl perl-dbd-pg postgresql-client
RUN cpan App::cpanminus
RUN cpanm App::Sqitch --no-wget --notest --quiet
RUN rm -rf /root/.cpan


# Build is the base with the installed npm packages
FROM base AS build

ENV TZ UTC

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm ci


# test creates the build for testing and can be used later for prod
FROM build AS test

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN chmod +x scripts/wait-for
RUN chmod +x scripts/restore_databases

# THIS WORKS JUST FINE
# When I ssh into the container after it gets built, I see the compiled code and can run it
RUN npm run build


# dev adds an additional dependencies needed for container management
# in our dev environment
FROM test AS dev
RUN apk add netcat-openbsd

WORKDIR /app


# release builds from a lighter node image and copies stuff over
# from tested build
FROM mhart/alpine-node:slim-12.18.3 AS release

ENV TZ UTC

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=test /app/node_modules /app/build /app/db_changes ./
```

```
docker-compose.yml

version: '3.7'

volumes:
  pgdata:
      external: false
  databases:
      external: false

services:
    api:
      container_name: server
      build: 
        context: .
        target: dev
      env_file:
        - .env
      volumes:
        - ./src:/app/src
        - ./db_changes:/app/db_changes
        - ./db_install/logs:/app/logs
        - ./scripts:/app/scripts
        - ./package.json:/app/package.json
        - ./tsconfig.json:/app/tsconfig.json
        - ./jest.config.js:/app/jest.config.js
      ports:
        - 5000:5000
        - 5001:5001
        - 5002:5002
        - 5003:5003
      command: sh -c "chmod +x ./scripts/wait-for && ./scripts/wait-for db:5432 -- ${COMMAND:-npm run migrate && npm run dev}"
```

Running: `docker-compose run api sh` to get into the shell and then `npm run build` produces OOM. Running `NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=512" npm run build` compiles successfully.

```
Docker version 19.03.12, build 48a66213fe
docker-compose version 1.27.2, build 18f557f9
node v12.18.3
typescript Version 3.8.3
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you use a VM to run the Docker daemon? I so, how much memory it has and does it have swap file? Also, did you read Docker's runtime options for memory (https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#memory) ?

Comment: I don't use a VM - it runs directly on my os (macOS 10.15.6 Catalina) - I just start up docker through the app. I did read the runtime options for memory, but not sure how that helps? My container has plenty of memory and comes no where close to using it all as indicated by the `docker stats` output.