# NODE_MODULES 4096 value not working for javascript heap out of memory error

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

When I run my vue app using `npm run serve` it says

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

I tried to follow instruction on increasing `node_options` space to `4096`,

I tried to do the following:
**1.** `Control panel` > `System` > `Advanced System Settings` > `Environment Variables`
**2.** Under `user variables for <user>` > `NODE_OPTIONS = --max-old-space-size=8192` #I doubled 4096 since error still persist for 4096

But I still got the same error. Any idea on how I resolve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory in ionic 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53230823/fatal-error-ineffective-mark-compacts-near-heap-limit-allocation-failed-javas)

Comment: Issue basically relates to poorly optimized code that eventually causes memory leaks in your dev environment. Instead of trying to throw more hardware at it, why not profile your code instead to figure out why that's the case?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy yes, but hard to track where it went wrong since it has a long line of code, basically made new version of this component T_T

Comment: You have a memory leak most likely, and a big one at that. You need to profile the JS and find the cause of the leak.

Comment: Based on your info, this could be happening because of code that you have in `created()` or `mounted()` you don't un-do in `beforeDestroy()` or `destroyed()` in your dev environment and the HMR isn't releasing the memory causing this leak.