# how to set --max_old_space_size and how to get actuall size?

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm using Angular 8.2.
When I build project on vps server ,
I'm facing the following issue:

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory What does that mean? How do I fix that? The full error message is: FATAL ERROR: Ineffective ...
```

Comment: export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"

Comment: you can see [ref link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53230823/fatal-error-ineffective-mark-compacts-near-heap-limit-allocation-failed-javas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command for build

```
node --max_old_space_size=16192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod
```