# Tests slow and crashing on new Angular 11 project

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage

I created a blank Angular project using Angular 11 and have 2 or 3 of the simplest tests. Running npm test, and more so when using the --code-coverage flag causes the tests to crash.
This did not happen on Angular 10. Do you have an idea what may be causing this?

```
03 03 2021 09:02:05.715:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
⠼ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...
<--- Last few GCs --->

[42284:0x108008000]    89381 ms: Scavenge (reduce) 4078.5 (4086.9) -> 4078.0 (4088.4) MB, 4.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.299, current mu = 0.269) allocation failure 
[42284:0x108008000]    89460 ms: Scavenge (reduce) 4078.8 (4087.4) -> 4078.2 (4088.4) MB, 77.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.299, current mu = 0.269) allocation failure 
[42284:0x108008000]    89482 ms: Scavenge (reduce) 4078.9 (4090.4) -> 4078.4 (4090.6) MB, 21.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.299, current mu = 0.269) allocation failure 


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x1012b7fd5 node::Abort() (.cold.1) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 2: 0x1000a3fa9 node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 3: 0x1000a410f node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 4: 0x1001e57f7 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 5: 0x1001e5793 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 6: 0x100383775 v8::internal::Heap::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 7: 0x10038523a v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 8: 0x100380909 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 9: 0x10037e1a1 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/bin/node]
10: 0x10038ca3a v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithLightRetrySlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/local/bin/node]
11: 0x10038cac1 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/local/bin/node]
12: 0x10035a487 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [/usr/local/bin/node]
13: 0x1006d8bc0 v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInOldGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
14: 0x100a4faf9 Builtins_CEntry_Return1_DontSaveFPRegs_ArgvOnStack_NoBuiltinExit [/usr/local/bin/node]
15: 0x2742bf38ba6a 
zsh: abort      npm test
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52390439/6513921

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory in ionic 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53230823/fatal-error-ineffective-mark-compacts-near-heap-limit-allocation-failed-javas)