# yarn build not working and gave me error 134

Tags: reactjs, npm, web-deployment, yarnpkg, netlify

I try to run yarn build to deploy my website at netlify but the frontend dont let me build. Anyone know how to fix this? I have tried to update my node and npm. My node is currently v14.16.1 and my npm is 7.11.0.

```
PS D:\ConHut\frontend> yarn build

conhut@0.1.0 build
react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...

<--- Last few GCs --->

[21860:00000283A1EAF380]    52651 ms: Scavenge (reduce) 4057.5 (4070.9) -> 4056.9 (4071.7) MB, 5.3 / 
0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.363, current mu = 0.461) allocation failure       
[21860:00000283A1EAF380]    52656 ms: Scavenge (reduce) 4057.7 (4068.7) -> 4057.1 (4069.7) MB, 3.9 / 
0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.363, current mu = 0.461) allocation failure       
[21860:00000283A1EAF380]    52660 ms: Scavenge (reduce) 4057.8 (4068.7) -> 4057.3 (4069.9) MB, 4.0 / 
0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.363, current mu = 0.461) allocation failure       


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of 
memory
1: 00007FF70FD0046F napi_wrap+109311
2: 00007FF70FCA5156 
v8::internal::OrderedHashTable<v8::internal::OrderedHashMap,2>::NumberOfElementsOffset+33302
3: 00007FF70FCA5F26 node::OnFatalError+294
4: 00007FF710572B4E v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+94
5: 00007FF71055792D v8::SharedArrayBuffer::Externalize+781
6: 00007FF710401CCC v8::internal::Heap::EphemeronKeyWriteBarrierFromCode+1516
7: 00007FF71040D04A v8::internal::Heap::ProtectUnprotectedMemoryChunks+1258
8: 00007FF71040A1F9 v8::internal::Heap::PageFlagsAreConsistent+2457
9: 00007FF7103FEDE1 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage+2033
10: 00007FF7103FD005 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateExternalBackingStore+1317
11: 00007FF71041D2A7 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject+183
12: 00007FF71014CABF v8::internal::interpreter::JumpTableTargetOffsets::iterator::operator=+1039
13: 00007FF7105FB50D v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+463949
 14: 0000030C625A0C99
 PS D:\ConHut\frontend>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53230823/fatal-error-ineffective-mark-compacts-near-heap-limit-allocation-failed-javas