# Error importing .json file to Firestore with firestore-import

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I exported my Firestore database using `firestore-export` and wrote it to a `json` file.

I had to read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53230823/fatal-error-ineffective-mark-compacts-near-heap-limit-allocation-failed-javas) in order to get the data written to the file properly. I decided to increase the memory space with this command:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=16384"
```

I also updated to node version 16, it was recommended to update to the latest version.

```
$ node --version
v16.2.0
```

When I tried to import that file to another database instance for redundancy, it did not work.

```
firestore-import -a admin-sdk-key.json -b export.json
```

Only some of the data was written and the operation aborted. The full error output is on Pastebin linked here:

https://pastebin.com/qAYrkk1X

A lot of the errors looked like this

```
Caused by: Error
    at WriteBatch.commit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-firestore-import-export/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:415:23)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-firestore-import-export/dist/lib/import.js:67:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at setDocuments (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-firestore-import-export/dist/lib/import.js:52:34)
    at Object.importData [as firestoreImport] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-firestore-import-export/dist/lib/import.js:26:41)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-firestore-import-export/dist/bin/firestore-import.js:77:17
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-firestore-import-export/dist/bin/firestore-import.js:6:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  code: 13,
  details: 'Received RST_STREAM with code 2',
  metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map(0) {}, options: {} },
  note: 'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error `Error: 8 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Bandwidth exhausted` found in the provided logs indicates that the project exceeded either its quota or the region/multi-region capacity, so probably your app is doing more reads than expected.

You can check more information in [this link](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/errors) or [this one](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas).

If you choose to allow your app to go further than the free quotas, [you must enable billing for your Cloud Platform project](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project).