# npm run build on my react app gives error => (Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out out of memory)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I also tried
**$env:NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8000"**
and set my max memory 8000 still it gives
the same error whenever I ***npm run build***

so I am not able to deploy

I have 8GB RAM
I don't know what else I can do

```
PS C:\Users\91955\Desktop\SFmovies\frontend> npm run build

> frontend@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...

<--- Last few GCs --->

[17892:000001D77EA8E2A0]    36182 ms: Scavenge 2034.0 (2082.8) -> 2032.4 (2083.0) MB, 3.1 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.183, current mu = 0.156) allocation failure
[17892:000001D77EA8E2A0]    36186 ms: Scavenge 2034.5 (2083.0) -> 2032.8 (2083.3) MB, 2.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.183, current mu = 0.156) allocation failure
[17892:000001D77EA8E2A0]    36190 ms: Scavenge 2035.0 (2083.5) -> 2033.3 (2087.8) MB, 2.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.183, current mu = 0.156) allocation failure


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF6526730AF v8::internal::CodeObjectRegistry::~CodeObjectRegistry+112511
 2: 00007FF652602216 DSA_meth_get_flags+65542
 3: 00007FF6526030CD node::OnFatalError+301
 4: 00007FF652F34B6E v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+94
 5: 00007FF652F1F09D v8::SharedArrayBuffer::Externalize+781
 6: 00007FF652DC268C v8::internal::Heap::EphemeronKeyWriteBarrierFromCode+1468
 7: 00007FF652DCF339 v8::internal::Heap::PublishPendingAllocations+1129
 8: 00007FF652DCC30A v8::internal::Heap::PageFlagsAreConsistent+2842
 9: 00007FF652DBEF89 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage+2137
10: 00007FF652DBD140 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateExternalBackingStore+2000
11: 00007FF652DE1A76 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject+214
12: 00007FF652B14CB5 v8::internal::DateCache::Weekday+1797
13: 00007FF652FC2541 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+494417
14: 000001D701EE9A38
```

Comment: Did you take a look to this post?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53230823/fatal-error-ineffective-mark-compacts-near-heap-limit-allocation-failed-javas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved my issue by
adding this under `"scripts"` in my package.json

```
"build": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=4096 build"
```

my Package.json if you have any doubt ..

[Package.json screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UzWU.png)