# Error while setting-up Ionic environment in Ubuntu 20 ec2 instance

Tags: node.js, angular, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ionic2

I am trying to generate the Android and IOS platform folders on the ubuntu server, so that I can transfer the same to a machine that is capable of building a .apk and .ipa for the same. I was successful in doing this with **Ionic CLI 6.18.1, @ionic/agular 5.9.3, cordova CLI: 10.0.0, and node 14.18.1**, but had a lot of **issues when upgrading** the project with **Ionic CLI 6.18.1, @ionic/agular 6.0.8, cordova CLI: 11.0.0 and node 16.14.0.**

***I would like to get some details on why this is happening and some document/video that I can refer to solve the same.***

> I have added the detailed error at the bottom

The error that I am constantly getting, only in ec2 instances are:

1. FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory [e1]
2. Error at new SubprocessError [e2]

The solution that I have tried:

To solve FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

1. set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192
2. changed package.json

   "scripts": {
   "ng-high-memory": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration=prod",
   }

   npm run ng-high-memory

Detailed error:

**[e1]** FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[10229:0x5132ba0]    64697 ms: Scavenge 479.8 (500.1) -> 479.5 (500.1) MB, 3.4 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.445, current mu = 0.476) allocation failure
[10229:0x5132ba0]    64721 ms: Scavenge 480.2 (500.1) -> 479.8 (504.1) MB, 22.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.445, current mu = 0.476) allocation failure


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0xb09980 node::Abort() [ng run app:ionic-cordova-build --platform=browser]
 2: 0xa1c235 node::FatalError(char const, char const) [ng run app:ionic-cordova-build --platform=browser]
 3: 0xcf77be v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate, char const, bool) [ng run app:ionic-cordova-build --platform=browser]
 4: 0xcf7b37 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate, char const, bool) [ng run app:ionic-cordova-build --platform=browser]
 5: 0xeaf3d5  [ng run app:ionic-cordova-build --platform=browser]
 6: 0xebf09d v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [ng run app:ionic-cordova-build --platform=browser]
 7: 0xec1d9e v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [ng run app:ionic-cordova-build --platform=browser]
 8: 0xe83257 v8::internal::Factory::New(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, v8::internal::AllocationType) [ng run app:ionic-cordova-build --platform=browser]
 9: 0xe93141 v8::internal::Factory::NewProperSubString(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, int, int) [ng run app:ionic-cordova-build --platform=browser]
10: 0x12123a5 v8::internal::Runtime_StringSplit(int, unsigned long, v8::internal::Isolate) [ng run app:ionic-cordova-build --platform=browser]
11: 0x15f0a99  [ng run app:ionic-cordova-build --platform=browser]
Error
```

**[e2]** Error at new SubprocessError

```
at new SubprocessError
(/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/node_modules/@ionic/utils-subprocess/dist/index.js:41:23)
at ChildProcess.<anonymous>
(/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/node_modules/@ionic/utils-subprocess/dist/index.js:125:27)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:520:28)
at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
[ec2-user@ip-10-100-0-156 ionic]$
```

Comment: See if you can find something useful in this Ionic 6 webinar from few days ago: https://ionic.io/resources/webinars/getting-started-with-ionic-6-livestream?utm_campaign=livestream_Ionic_6&utm_medium=email&_hsmi=204153389&_hsenc=p2ANqtz-9uSF3JpgXSBdE-bdp8aSgkG16JQ6TGE5NcZYA9NzvqCHbtpR2CUxQ4E5Zi-UQWVeqLpI1czUFc3LUu1udi6eBMT1SLxA&utm_content=65536063105&utm_source=hubspot Just fast-forward to 'Upgrading an existing app to V6' section.

Comment: Thank you  @Misha Mashina for helping, will definitely give a listen to it and try to see if it help.

Comment: Hi Misha Mashina, thanks for the suggesting the video. But I was not able solve the issue. I believe that " Reached heap limit Allocation failed" is triggered do to insufficient RAM or CPU. Do you have document that has the minimum requirement of a Ubuntu system to run Ionic in it ?

Comment: See about these suggestions of expanding node memory: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53230823/fatal-error-ineffective-mark-compacts-near-heap-limit-allocation-failed-javas , https://support.snyk.io/hc/en-us/articles/360002046418-JavaScript-heap-out-of-memory Might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I was able to solve the issue by upgrading the RAM from 1 to 2 GB (t2.micro - t2.small).**

We came to this conclusion by running series of test in VM(Virtual Machine) by replicating the same environment.

Thanks.