# yarn start FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

Receiving this error with `yarn start`

[image]

I tried many solutions with this error through stakeoverflow using this link [FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory in Ionic 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53230823/fatal-error-ineffective-mark-compacts-near-heap-limit-allocation-failed-javas) but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

you should addthis line in .env file in your project

GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false