# I can´t deploy an angular app to my app service on azure because of FATAL ERROR Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed

Tags: angular, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I´ve been trying to deploy my angular application to azure web service (web app service).

Steps:

1. Use a build pipeline to generate **an artifact (zip file)** in **Azure DevOps**
2. Use a release pipeline that uses the previous generated artifact to deploy to my app service
3. An error occurs

Notes:

1. The zip file has a **total size of 150MB**
2. I have used 2 different tasks without any success (**AzureWebApp@1** and **AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4**)

Can someone help me please ? Don't know if I'm doing something wrong or if there´s a known issue related to release pipelines

**STACKTRACE**

2023-08-13T05:07:14.5302848Z FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

2023-08-13T05:07:14.7863924Z  1: 00007FF6FEF489AA v8::internal::GCIdleTimeHandler::GCIdleTimeHandler+4506

2023-08-13T05:07:14.7866373Z  2: 00007FF6FEF234E6 node::MakeCallback+4534

2023-08-13T05:07:14.7869155Z  3: 00007FF6FEF23E60 node_module_register+2032

2023-08-13T05:07:14.7871100Z  4: 00007FF6FF242F4E v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+846

2023-08-13T05:07:14.7872124Z  5: 00007FF6FF242E7F v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+639

2023-08-13T05:07:14.7873097Z  6: 00007FF6FF429674 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+9620

2023-08-13T05:07:14.7874238Z  7: 00007FF6FF420656 v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+24550

2023-08-13T05:07:14.7875507Z  8: 00007FF6FF41ECAC v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+17980

2023-08-13T05:07:14.7876896Z  9: 00007FF6FF4279F7 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+2327

2023-08-13T05:07:14.7878550Z 10: 00007FF6FF427A76 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+2454

2023-08-13T05:07:14.7879539Z 11: 00007FF6FF551D17 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject+55

2023-08-13T05:07:14.7881203Z 12: 00007FF6FF5CEF06 v8::internal::operator<<+73494

2023-08-13T05:07:14.7881902Z 13: 000000B013FDC6C1

2023-08-13T05:07:15.2310298Z ##[error]Exit code 134 returned from process: file name 'C:\externals\node10\bin\node.exe', arguments '"C:_work_tasks\AzureWebApp_18bde28a-8172-45cb-b204-5cef1393dbb1\1.225.2\azurermwebappdeployment.js"'.

2023-08-13T05:07:15.2336536Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy Azure Web App Service

I have used 2 different tasks without any success (**AzureWebApp@1** and **AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4**)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve this error refer this [**npm commands**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/increase-memory-limit) for the same error code in your yaml pipeline and these [**SO thread answers**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53230823/fatal-error-ineffective-mark-compacts-near-heap-limit-allocation-failed-javas) like below:-

```yaml
trigger:
- master

variables:

  
  azureSubscription: '2b091df1-9e5a-4afa-a8d5-3646ec58c115'

  
  webAppName: 'valleywebapp98'

  
  environmentName: 'valleywebapp98'

  
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: $(environmentName)
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
            displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: valleywebapp98'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
              appType: webAppLinux
              WebAppName: $(webAppName)
              packageForLinux: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              RuntimeStack: 'NODE|10.10'
              StartupCommand: 'npm run start'
              ScriptType: 'Inline Script'
              InlineScript: |
                npm install
                npm run build --if-present
                npm install -g increase-memory-limit
                increase-memory-limit
                set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096
```

**Output:-**

[image]