# exceljs giving out of memory in writeBuffer method

Tags: javascript, out-of-memory, exceljs

I'm tring to use writeBuffer method but it is giving me, `Reached heap limit Allocation failed` error. It is working on small excel but giving an error on big ones. Is there any solution you know? I'm using exceljs.

```js
const fileAsBuffer = await workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer(); // giving out of memory error
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53230823/fatal-error-ineffective-mark-compacts-near-heap-limit-allocation-failed-javas

Comment: thanks, but I'm seeking a solution by not using ```NODE_OPTIONS --max-old-space-size```

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you could give us a little bit more information about the execution environment first.
The issue, most likely, appears due to the strict standard limit for memory usage in V8, but first check this

> Try to read this: https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/issues/2041

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35770941)