# Gulp - allocation failed - javascript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-inject

In my project i have to inject html, Css code dyncamically using gulp task with gulp-inject plugin.
Some times i need to write large size of html and js files. That moment i am getting "allocation failed - javascript heap out of memory" error while running the gulp task.

Can anyone suggests how to resolve this issue

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558989/node-js-heap-out-of-memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to Bump the rxjs version due to memory leak in old version

Ref for more details: https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/issues/259