# Nodejs / Javascript get the numbers between a start number and end number when each number has more than 15 digits

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, heap-memory, iccid

I was trying to get the numbers (iccid's - something reated to esim) between a start_number and end_number using the following logic :

```
let { start_iccid, end_iccid } = req.value.body;
let list = [];
let lowEnd = parseInt(start_iccid); // sample value : 100000000000000000
let highEnd = parseInt(end_iccid); // sample value : 100000000000000029
for (let i = lowEnd; i <= highEnd; i++) {
   list.push(i);
}
```

As expected i am getting the following errors :

```
FATAL ERROR: invalid array length Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [/home/cavli/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin/node]
 2: 0x8c21ec [/home/cavli/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin/node]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [/home/cavli/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin/node]
 4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [/home/cavli/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin/node]
 5: v8::internal::Heap::AllocateUninitializedFixedDoubleArray(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/home/cavli/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin/node]
 6: v8::internal::Factory::NewFixedDoubleArray(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/home/cavli/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin/node]
 7: 0xd554b5 [/home/cavli/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin/node]
 8: v8::internal::Runtime_GrowArrayElements(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/home/cavli/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin/node]
 9: 0x217d6df042fd
```

I understand that in Javascript, all numbers are **IEEE double precision floating point numbers**, which means that i only have about **16 digits** of precision; the remainder of the 64 bits are reserved for the exponent. And i have to work some tricks to get more precision if you need all 64 bits.

I tried to use [big-number](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-number) javascript library but could not make it work with `for` loop .

What would be the best possible solution to this problem ?

I also tried to increase the nodejs `memory limit` after reading this thread but couldn't solve the issue : [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558989/node-js-heap-out-of-memory)

**Note** : The biggest safe integer in JavaScript is 9007199254740991 (253-1), whereas the smallest safe integer is -9007199254740991 .

*ICCID (Integrated Circuit Card Identifier) - A SIM card contains its unique serial number (ICCID). ICCIDs are stored in the SIM cards and are also printed on the SIM card during a personalisation process. Can have 18 to 20 digits*

Comment: _"I tried to use big-number javascript library but could not make it work with for loop"_ - You will have to add this approach as well if you want to get help with it.

Comment: I don't think this is so much about huge numbers as it is about huge *arrays*. The error looks like you're trying to create an array with tons and tons of elements. (also, in case it is relevant: http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @ChrisG i had the same thought but as you can see , in the numbers its just a difference of 29  , so not sure if it is something related to array

Comment: I did a quick in-browser check and apparently the `i` in your loop doesn't get incremented properly. This turns the loop into an infinite one, which will consequently try to create an infinitely big array. So it is indeed a large number problem, which brings me back to the XY problem issue. What are you trying to do here? Why do you need an array full of huge numbers?

Comment: @ChrisG thanks for the answer ,  I was trying to get  all the  iccid's  ( something reated to esim)  in between  a start_iccid and end_iccid  which was given as input

Comment: @JoelJoseph check my answer. it might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question you want to get all numbers between 2 big numbers. you can use bignumber.js library https://www.npmjs.com/package/bignumber.js .it handles all operations related to big numbers.

```
const BigNumber = require('bignumber.js');


let arr = []; 
let x = new BigNumber("100000000000000000");
let y = "100000000000000029";
while (x.isLessThanOrEqualTo(y)) {
    arr.push(x.toString());
    x = x.plus(1);
}


for (let elem of arr) {
    console.log(elem); //it contains all your elements
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer , but i am getting  the following error `x.isLessThanOrEqualTo is not a function`  (i am running this code in nodejs app)

Comment: did you converted x to bignumer using `let x = new BigNumber("your number");`

Comment: This given code is running perfectly for me. may be you have installed some other bignumber js library. try to reinstall it using `npm install bignumber.js`

Comment: @yes you were right , i got the npm package wrong i installed `big-number` instead . Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add any number of digits. You may install lodash in your project or include external javascript.

```
import _ from "lodash";

let result = _.add(100000000000000000, 100000000000000029);
console.log(result);
```

You may refer the documentation from here [add two numbers using lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#add)