# array doesn't push expected element

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript and having this problem. Basically I have to check for invalid credit cards number

```
// All valid credit card numbers
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8]
const valid2 = [5, 5, 3, 5, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 8, 7, 5, 1, 4, 3, 9]
const valid3 = [3, 7, 1, 6, 1, 2, 0, 1, 9, 9, 8, 5, 2, 3, 6]
const valid4 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 0, 6, 8, 2, 9, 0, 5]
const valid5 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 4, 0, 4, 9, 6, 7, 8, 6, 9, 6, 6, 6]

// All invalid credit card numbers
const invalid1 = [4, 5, 3, 2, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 1, 0, 9, 1, 7, 9, 5]
const invalid2 = [5, 7, 9, 5, 5, 9, 3, 3, 9, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 4, 3]
const invalid3 = [3, 7, 5, 7, 9, 6, 0, 8, 4, 4, 5, 9, 9, 1, 4]
const invalid4 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7, 9, 6, 1, 7, 7, 7, 9, 3, 5]
const invalid5 = [5, 3, 8, 2, 0, 1, 9, 7, 7, 2, 8, 8, 3, 8, 5, 4]

// Can be either valid or invalid
const mystery1 = [3, 4, 4, 8, 0, 1, 9, 6, 8, 3, 0, 5, 4, 1, 4]
const mystery2 = [5, 4, 6, 6, 1, 0, 0, 8, 6, 1, 6, 2, 0, 2, 3, 9]
const mystery3 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 3, 7, 7, 0, 2, 0, 9, 6, 2, 6, 5, 6, 2, 0, 3]
const mystery4 = [4, 9, 2, 9, 8, 7, 7, 1, 6, 9, 2, 1, 7, 0, 9, 3]
const mystery5 = [4, 9, 1, 3, 5, 4, 0, 4, 6, 3, 0, 7, 2, 5, 2, 3]

// An array of all the arrays above
const batch = [valid1, valid2, valid3, valid4, valid5, invalid1, invalid2, invalid3, invalid4, invalid5, mystery1, mystery2, mystery3, mystery4, mystery5]
```

The validity of a credit card is accessed by this algorithm (Luhn algorithm):

```
function validateCred(card_number){
let sum = card_number[card_number.length-1];
let flag = 1;
for (i = card_number.length-2; i >= 0; i--){
    if (flag % 2 !== 0){
        card_number[i] *= 2;
        if (card_number[i] > 9){
            card_number[i] -= 9;
        }
    }
    sum += card_number[i];
    flag++;
}

if (sum % 10 === 0){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
}
```

And I have to create an array with all the invalid cards:

```
function findInvalidCards(numbers){
    let invalid_array = [];
    for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
        if (!validateCred(numbers[i])){
            invalid_array.push(numbers[i]);
        }
    }
    return invalid_array;
}
```

When I call the `findInValidCards` function, it raises the `heap out of memory` error, I tried to follow the solution from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558989/node-js-heap-out-of-memory) and raise the usage memory to 8gb but the problem persists. After debugging, I found out that this line `invalid_array.push(numbers[i])` actually appends a `undefined` variable to the array, not the element that I wanted. What could possibly cause this problem?

Comment: The code you've posted shouldn't produce any of the behaviour you describe - there shouldn't be an out of memory error, nor should `numbers[i]` ever resolve to `undefined`. However, the behaviour does imply that something else is modifying the `numbers` array and you might even be calling this recursively or in a loop or something. Your description hints at the problem being elsewhere.

Comment: you need to declare `i` for each function. otherwise `i` changes the value erraticly.

Comment: to elaborate on what @NinaScholz said, try `for (var i =...` or `for (let i =...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nina had said in the comments, you should be defining `i` with `let` each time you're writing the for loop or else you're going to have unpredictable behavior

However, you also had an issue in your `validateCred` function where you were mutating the original Array while checking it - you can simply clone the input Array with `let clone = card_number.slice(0);`, and then reference `clone` for your checks

Also, you can simplify `findInvalidCards` by using [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), like:

```js
function findInvalidCards(numbers) {
  return numbers.filter(x => !validateCred(x));
}
```

```js
// All valid credit card numbers
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8];
const valid2 = [5, 5, 3, 5, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 8, 7, 5, 1, 4, 3, 9];
const valid3 = [3, 7, 1, 6, 1, 2, 0, 1, 9, 9, 8, 5, 2, 3, 6];
const valid4 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 0, 6, 8, 2, 9, 0, 5];
const valid5 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 4, 0, 4, 9, 6, 7, 8, 6, 9, 6, 6, 6];

// All invalid credit card numbers
const invalid1 = [4, 5, 3, 2, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 1, 0, 9, 1, 7, 9, 5];
const invalid2 = [5, 7, 9, 5, 5, 9, 3, 3, 9, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 4, 3];
const invalid3 = [3, 7, 5, 7, 9, 6, 0, 8, 4, 4, 5, 9, 9, 1, 4];
const invalid4 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7, 9, 6, 1, 7, 7, 7, 9, 3, 5];
const invalid5 = [5, 3, 8, 2, 0, 1, 9, 7, 7, 2, 8, 8, 3, 8, 5, 4];

// Can be either valid or invalid
const mystery1 = [3, 4, 4, 8, 0, 1, 9, 6, 8, 3, 0, 5, 4, 1, 4];
const mystery2 = [5, 4, 6, 6, 1, 0, 0, 8, 6, 1, 6, 2, 0, 2, 3, 9];
const mystery3 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 3, 7, 7, 0, 2, 0, 9, 6, 2, 6, 5, 6, 2, 0, 3];
const mystery4 = [4, 9, 2, 9, 8, 7, 7, 1, 6, 9, 2, 1, 7, 0, 9, 3];
const mystery5 = [4, 9, 1, 3, 5, 4, 0, 4, 6, 3, 0, 7, 2, 5, 2, 3];

// An array of all the arrays above
const batch = [valid1, valid2, valid3, valid4, valid5, invalid1, invalid2, invalid3, invalid4, invalid5, mystery1, mystery2, mystery3, mystery4, mystery5];

function validateCred(card_number) {
  let clone = card_number.slice(0);

  let sum = clone[clone.length - 1];
  let flag = 1;

  for (i = clone.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (flag % 2 !== 0) {
      clone[i] *= 2;
      if (clone[i] > 9) {
        clone[i] -= 9;
      }
    }

    sum += clone[i];
    flag++;
  }

  if (sum % 10 === 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};

// And I have to create an array with all the invalid cards:
function findInvalidCards(numbers) {
  let invalid_array = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (!validateCred(numbers[i])) {
      invalid_array.push(numbers[i]);
    }
  }
  return invalid_array;
}

let invalidCardArray = findInvalidCards(batch);

// Prettier console.log()
invalidCardArray.forEach(x => console.log(validateCred(x) + ':', ...x));
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. Can you elaborate more about why doesn't it throw an error if I don't define "i" for each loop?

Comment: Without defining `i` it's added to the global scope, so both of your for loops are changing the same variable - When you use [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) you're scoping it only to that block of code, so this crossover doesn't happen

Answer (score 1):

The `i` variable is defined as global if you don't define it with `var` or `let`. So when it starts from `findInvalidCards` function the `i` value is zero but when it access the `validateCred` function, the i value changes.So when it will finish from `validateCred` function, `i` value will be `-1` and it will try to increment it in `findInvalidCards` for loop and `i` value will be zero.That will happen over and over again,it will go in infinite loop causing the memory exception and everything crashes.

I have debug your code, so i know how it goes. :)

```
  function findInvalidCards(numbers){
        let invalid_array = [];
        //make i local variable by defining it let or var, otherwise it will be global
        for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
            if (!validateCred(numbers[i])){
                invalid_array.push(numbers[i]);
            }
        }
        return invalid_array;
    }

function validateCred(card_number){
    let sum = card_number[card_number.length-1];
    let flag = 1;
    //make i local variable by defining it let or var, otherwise it will be global
    for (var i = card_number.length-2; i >= 0; i--){
        if (flag % 2 !== 0){
            card_number[i] *= 2;
            if (card_number[i] > 9){
                card_number[i] -= 9;
            }
        }
        sum += card_number[i];
        flag++;
    }

    if (sum % 10 === 0){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```