# Joining Discord Voice chat at a given time

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm coding a bot that auto-enters a voice chat at midnight, and then plays a song.

I've tried using this:

```
 // require the discord.js module
const Discord = require('discord.js');

// create a new Discord client
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require('fs');
const broadcast = client.voice.createBroadcast();
// Checks the date
var date = new Date()


// when the client is ready, run this code
// this event will only trigger one time after logging in

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.login(token);

function timeReached(){
    setInterval(function(){ date = new Date(); }, 30000);
    if (date.getHours() === 14 && date.getMinutes() === 8) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    }

client.on("ready", () => {
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get("my chat");
    if (!channel) return console.error("The channel does not exist!");
    while (timeReached != true)
    {
        timeReached();
    }
    const conection = channel.connect();
    const dispatcher = connection.play ("audio.mp3");
    setTimeout(function(){
        connection.disconnect();
    }, 5000)    
});
```

But after a while running, this message appears on the console:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[13860:00000136C7E96090]    23337 ms: Scavenge 2028.1 (2035.6) -> 2027.6 (2036.4) MB, 9.1 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.142, current mu = 0.062) allocation failure
[13860:00000136C7E96090]    23346 ms: Scavenge 2028.8 (2036.4) -> 2028.3 (2047.1) MB, 6.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.142, current mu = 0.062) allocation failure
[13860:00000136C7E96090]    23485 ms: Scavenge 2035.3 (2047.1) -> 2034.5 (2040.1) MB, 10.3 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.142, current mu = 0.062) allocation failure


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 00007FF7E62C77DD]
Security context: 0x0261bc4408d1 <JSObject>
    1: incRefCount(aka incRefCount) [0000021BF3E94141] [internal/timers.js:~289] [pc=0000019AF4857628](this=0x0042117804b1 <undefined>)
    2: /* anonymous */ [0000025542A3FFC9] [C:\Users\R2\Desktop\oleo_de_macaco_bot\index.js:~34] [pc=0000019AF485910C](this=0x03aac97c2429 <EventEmitter map = 00000101FF0CA349>)
    3: emit [000003FAB26E3969] [events.js:327...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF7E56B470F napi_wrap+113583
 2: 00007FF7E565F7D6 v8::base::CPU::has_sse+66646
 3: 00007FF7E56605D6 v8::base::CPU::has_sse+70230
 4: 00007FF7E5E742EE v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+94
 5: 00007FF7E5E5C3C1 v8::SharedArrayBuffer::Externalize+833
 6: 00007FF7E5D2890C v8::internal::Heap::EphemeronKeyWriteBarrierFromCode+1436
 7: 00007FF7E5D33B40 v8::internal::Heap::ProtectUnprotectedMemoryChunks+1312
 8: 00007FF7E5D30664 v8::internal::Heap::PageFlagsAreConsistent+3204
 9: 00007FF7E5D25E63 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage+1283
10: 00007FF7E5D2C6F4 v8::internal::Heap::GlobalSizeOfObjects+212
11: 00007FF7E5D6251B v8::internal::StackGuard::HandleInterrupts+907
12: 00007FF7E5AAD719 v8::internal::interpreter::JumpTableTargetOffsets::iterator::operator=+7737
13: 00007FF7E62C77DD v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+546637
14: 0000019AF4857628
```

Judging by this line:

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

It seems to be that my bot is running out of memory. How can I alocate more memory to it or circuvent this problem?

P.S.: It is my very first bot, and i know very little about javascript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js heap out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558989/node-js-heap-out-of-memory)

Answer (score 2):

Near the bottom of your code, I see this `while` loop:

```js
while (timeReached != true)
{
    timeReached();
}
```

I'm not exactly certain what you're trying to do here, but `timeReached` is a function, and so that condition, `timeReached != true`, always returns `true`, which means that `timeReached()` will be called repeatedly until the program terminates. This is where I'd assume the error is coming from.

Try changing the code to see if the **value the function returns** is not true (notice the parenthesis):

```
while (timeReached() != true)
{
    timeReached();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I've implemented your change, but the problem still persists. The middle lines have suffered slight alterations, but the error message remains the same.

Comment: Could you tell me what you want to achieve with the `timeReached()` function? That'll help me solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the interval created inside of the `timeReached` function is resulting in a huge memory leak.

Since you are always checking if the date is reached inside of your while statement, I think that you should replace the following line in your hour-checking function (`setInterval(function(){ date = new Date(); }, 30000);`) to simply `const date = new Date();`

Comment: I've changed that already and it seems to be working now. Just need to tweak the room-joining code. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @LucasMoura try to replace your `channel.connect()` with `channel.join()` ;)

Comment: Now the problem lies on the "connection.play('audio.mp3'); " bit. It is not being recoganized as a valid function.

Comment: @LucasMoura you should switch to a `.then(connection => {` callback in that case (right after joining the channel), and make sure to move all the code below the join function inside of the new callback (.then)

Comment: @LucasMoura glad I could have helped :)