# React npm start not working at it fails when reinstalling

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install, npm-start

When npm start it shows this error and I dont know where is comming from.
I have reinstalled multiple times but it doesnt fix.

Starting the development server...

<--- Last few GCs --->

[6398:0x1bb7020]    76545 ms: Mark-sweep 1354.5 (1423.5) -> 1353.5 (1423.5) MB, 3677.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.101, current mu = 0.007) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[6398:0x1bb7020]    79992 ms: Mark-sweep 1354.9 (1423.5) -> 1353.9 (1424.0) MB, 3311.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.072, current mu = 0.039) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed

<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

```
0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x274050a5452b]
```

Security context: 0x0c197abaede9 
1: append [0x1bdeaa895e81] [/home/oddstats-react/node_modules/@babel/generator/lib/buffer.js:~61] [pc=0x27405127e3ec](this=0x1cf75f802311 ,str=0x2dffdf407d01 <String[1]: 0>)
2: NumericLiteral [0x1bdeaa897261] [/home/oddstats-react/node_modules/@babel/generator/lib/generators/types.js:~197] [pc=0x2740512cc529](this=0x1cf75...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
1: 0x7f2d8b362568 node::Abort() [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.64]
2: 0x7f2d8b3625b1  [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.64]
3: 0x7f2d8b523d22 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.64]
4: 0x7f2d8b523f78 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.64]
5: 0x7f2d8b8a55f2  [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.64]
6: 0x7f2d8b8b6023 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.64]
7: 0x7f2d8b8b6936 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.64]
8: 0x7f2d8b8b907d v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithLigthRetry(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.64]
9: 0x7f2d8b8b90d2 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.64]
10: 0x7f2d8b887a74 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationSpace) [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.64]
11: 0x7f2d8baf1ca5 v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInNewSpace(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.64]
12: 0x274050a5452b
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! oddstats-react@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the oddstats-react@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-01-13T18_43_19_151Z-debug.log

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558989/node-js-heap-out-of-memory