# Heap of out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I am having problem with the memory when I try to start my react app with npm start. The error says

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[12380:006AE720]    71751 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 1215.6 (1266.1) -> 683.3 (1175.2) MB, 195.0 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.962, current mu = 0.970) last resort GC in old space requested
[12380:006AE720]    72125 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 683.3 (1163.2) -> 682.6 (1010.2) MB, 374.0 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.897, current mu = 0.000) last resort GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

In package.json file inside the scripts I have `"start": "nodemon --max-old-space-size=48000 -w app.js -w webpack.config.js app.js"` but unfortunately it does not solve the problem. I also tried everything in this post [Node.js heap out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558989/node-js-heap-out-of-memory) but still having same problem.

This is the node-clinic report

[image]

These are the warnings&errors from node-clinic

```
buffer.js:429
    return createFromString(string, ops.encodingVal);
           ^

    Error: Failed to allocate memory
        at createFromString (<anonymous>)
        at fromStringFast (buffer.js:429:12)
        at fromString (buffer.js:458:10)
        at Function.from (buffer.js:308:12)
        at new Buffer (buffer.js:289:17)
        at writeOut (C:\Users\User\documents\costaa\costa\fe\explorebook\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:334:17)
        at Immediate.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\documents\costaa\costa\fe\explorebook\node_modules\memory-fs\lib\MemoryFileSystem.js:288:4)
        at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:462:21) {
      code: 'ERR_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_FAILED'
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the app at startup? Could you use node-clinicjs to see what is leaking the memory?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon Hi I have added node-clinic report in question

Comment: What Node version are you using?

Comment: @eol Node version v14.17.0 and npm version 6.14.13

Comment: Could not be a case where the user triggers an infinity loop?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon it can be but issue solved by changing node version. Thanks for answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved issue by changing `node` version which I was using `14.17.0` and I switched to `14.10.1`. I have used `nvm-windows` to switch node versions