# Mongoose Error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in NestJs

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I am using nests framework and versions of mongodb and mongoose are as specified below.
Please refer to the screenshot for error in detail.

**versions**

```
"mongodb": "4.0.0",
"mongoose": "5.5.12",
```

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xf2o.jpg)

**User Document Module**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserDocumentsService } from './user-documents.service';
import { UserDocumentsController } from './user-documents.controller';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { UserDocumentsSchema } from './schema/user-documents.schema';

@Module({
    imports: [
        // showing error on this line
        MongooseModule.forFeature([
            { name: 'UserDocument', schema: UserDocumentsSchema },
        ]),
    ],
    controllers: [UserDocumentsController],
    providers: [UserDocumentsService],
})
export class UserDocumentsModule {}
```

**App.module.ts**

```
@Module({
imports: [
        MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
            imports: [SharedModule],
            useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
                uri: configService.mongoDBName(),
                useNewUrlParser: true,
                useFindAndModify: false,
            }),
            inject: [ConfigService],
        }),
        UserDocumentsModule,
    ],
    providers: [AppGateway],
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
    configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer): MiddlewareConsumer | void {
        consumer.apply(contextMiddleware).forRoutes('*');
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
I think there is something wrong with the mongoose imports in the schema file. It says "could not find declaration for module 'mongoose'".

[image: Import error]

I tried removing and reinstalling mongoose and it's types. But now it shows new error.

[image: JavaScript heap out of memory]

I tried solutions mentioned in this post:
[Node.js heap out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558989/node-js-heap-out-of-memory)

But this also didn't work for me.
I'm using Mac-M1 with 8GB config.

**UPDATE**
The issue has been resolved now. The project is running on node v10.24.1 and I was using node v16.6.2.
After downgrading node version using NVM, this issue is gone.

Comment: How is your app.module.ts? 
Please add it to your question.

Comment: @PauloFabrício please have a look.

Comment: Why are you importing the `SharedModule` into the `MongooseModule`? In generell you have to import the `ConfigModule` from `@nestjs/config`. Does this fix your issue?

Comment: @LarsFlieger the problem still persists even after removing shared module from mongoose imports. I don't think that should be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because I was using a wrong version of node. The project was built on node v10.24.1 and I was using node v16.6.2.

After downgrading node version using NVM, I was able to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to pull SharedModule import off MongooseModule.

Try this:

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
            useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
                uri: configService.mongoDBName(),
                useNewUrlParser: true,
                useFindAndModify: false,
            }),
            inject: [ConfigService],
        }),
        UserDocumentsModule,
        SharedModule
    ],
    providers: [AppGateway],
})

export class AppModule implements NestModule {
    configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer): MiddlewareConsumer | void {
        consumer.apply(contextMiddleware).forRoutes('*');
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem still persists even after removing shared module from mongoose imports.

Comment: Try to remove the folder node_modules and run npm install

Comment: I did that. But now it shows "Javascript heap out of memory". The same project is running well and good on my other colleagues system. and the setup is exactly the same. 

I am still digging into the issue and will update as soon as I find something.

Comment: Did you reinstall node?