# Node.js javascript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've developed a nodejs app, and made exe out of it using npm library called "pkg". Now while using command prompt, if I run that "script.exe"(open command prompt in the location of script.exe, and type "script.exe",hit enter button), then I'm getting "javascript heap out of memory" error. How to resolve itt?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js heap out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558989/node-js-heap-out-of-memory)

Comment: No, I'm mking it exe using 'pkg' npm llibrary and running it in cmd