# Sometimes when I run `npx hardhat compile` I get this error: FATAL ERROR: NewNativeModule Allocation failed - process out of memor

Tags: chainlink, hardhat

Sometimes when I run this command `npx hardhat compile` on my windows cli I get the error below:

```
Compiling 72 files with 0.7.0
contracts/libraries/ERC20.sol: Warning: SPDX license identifier not provided in source file. Before publishing, consider adding a comment containing "SPDX-License-Identifier: <SPDX-License>" to each source file. Use "SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED" for non-open-source code. 
Please see https://spdx.org for more information.

contracts/libraries/ERC1155/EnumerableSet.sol:158:5: Warning: Variable is shadowed in inline assembly by an instruction of the same name    
    function add(Bytes32Set storage set, bytes32 value) internal returns (bool) {
    ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

contracts/libraries/ERC1155/EnumerableSet.sol:224:5: Warning: Variable is shadowed in inline assembly by an instruction of the same name    
    function add(AddressSet storage set, address value) internal returns (bool) {
    ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

Compiling 1 file with 0.8.0

<--- Last few GCs --->

[8432:042B0460]   263058 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 349.8 (356.3) -> 248.2 (262.4) MB, 434.4 / 0.2 ms  (+ 70.9 ms in 3 steps since start of marking, biggest step 69.6 ms, walltime since start of marking 800 ms) (average mu = 0.989, current mu = 0.990) memory[8432:042B0460]   263627 
ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 248.2 (259.4) -> 248.2 (252.1) MB, 555.5 / 0.0 ms  (+ 0.0 ms in 0 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 556 ms) (average mu = 0.969, current 
mu = 0.023) memory p

<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: NewNativeModule Allocation failed - process out of memory`
```

After some time the error just kind of goes away.

It goes away probably after I've restarted my system or created a new Hardhat project and imported the code there.

**But this is happening too often, what could be the cause?**

I've done quite some research and some answers suggested it might be a problem with Node and the application's memory allocation, but I don't know how I would apply the solutions to a Hardhat project.

Here is a link to one possible solution: https://medium.com/@vuongtran/how-to-solve-process-out-of-memory-in-node-js-5f0de8f8464c

OS: WINDOWS 10 
CLI: WINDOWS CMD

Comment: Can you please copy paste your error instead of the screenshot?

Comment: Sure Patrick. I just did that

Comment: I keep experiencing this issue in different hard projects after working on it for sometime. Here is another reference i found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558989/node-js-heap-out-of-memory

Comment: Incase anyone encounters this in future, i was recommended to this: https://hardhat.org/troubleshooting/common-problems.html#out-of-memory-errors-when-compiling-large-projects

Comment: Did that work for you?

Comment: Heyy Patrick, it didnt actually... Just put it there incase it helps someone else in future. Thanks for your concern tho