# Angular build `FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

Tags: angular

I'm getting the following error when building angular app for production.
I have increased `--max-old-space-size`, but the build is failing periodically because I've hit the system memory limit in a github runner. How I would go about debugging what is causing the high memory usage?

On node 16.

`
✔ Copying assets complete.

- Generating index html...

<--- Last few GCs --->

[2057:0x5803630]   298376 ms: Mark-sweep 1982.3 (2089.2) -> 1973.3 (2096.0) MB, 3538.3 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.481, current mu = 0.093) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[2057:0x5803630]   301731 ms: Mark-sweep 1979.4 (2096.0) -> 1976.3 (2098.5) MB, 3287.8 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.305, current mu = 0.020) allocation failure GC in old space requested

<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
1: 0xb090e0 node::Abort() [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.20.2/x64/bin/node]
2: 0xa1b70e  [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.20.2/x64/bin/node]
3: 0xce1a20 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.20.2/x64/bin/node]
4: 0xce1dc7 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.20.2/x64/bin/node]
5: 0xe99435  [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.20.2/x64/bin/node]
6: 0xea90fd v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.20.2/x64/bin/node]
7: 0xeabdfe v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.20.2/x64/bin/node]
8: 0xe6d072 v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRaw(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.20.2/x64/bin/node]
9: 0xe6798c v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::AllocateRawArray(int, v8::internal::AllocationType) [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.20.2/x64/bin/node]
10: 0xe67a65 v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewFixedArrayWithFiller(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Oddball>, v8::internal::AllocationType) [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.20.2/x64/bin/node]
11: 0xfc0b4d v8::internal::DeoptimizationData::New(v8::internal::Isolate*, int, v8::internal::AllocationType) [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.20.2/x64/bin/node]
12: 0x1c19e53 v8::internal::compiler::CodeGenerator::GenerateDeoptimizationData() [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.20.2/x64/bin/node]
13: 0x1c1a575 v8::internal::compiler::CodeGenerator::FinalizeCode() [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.20.2/x64/bin/node]
14: 0x1ca2a31 v8::internal::compiler::PipelineImpl::FinalizeCode(bool) [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.20.2/x64/bin/node]
15: 0x1ca3a33 v8::internal::compiler::PipelineCompilationJob::FinalizeJobImpl(v8::internal::Isolate*) [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.20.2/x64/bin/node]
16: 0xd79390 v8::internal::OptimizedCompilationJob::FinalizeJob(v8::internal::Isolate*) [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.20.2/x64/bin/node]
17: 0xd7df4b v8::internal::Compiler::FinalizeOptimizedCompilationJob(v8::internal::OptimizedCompilationJob*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.20.2/x64/bin/node]
18: 0xda0253 v8::internal::OptimizingCompileDispatcher::InstallOptimizedFunctions() [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.20.2/x64/bin/node]
19: 0xe39287 v8::internal::StackGuard::HandleInterrupts() [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.20.2/x64/bin/node]
20: 0x11e5ab4 v8::internal::Runtime_StackGuardWithGap(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.20.2/x64/bin/node]
21: 0x15d9e59  [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.20.2/x64/bin/node]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call Nodejs's garbage collection on Angular jest tests? Tests are slow and leaking memory with node v20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77575194/how-to-call-nodejss-garbage-collection-on-angular-jest-tests-tests-are-slow-an)

Comment: Unfortunately no, my issue is happening on build not tests, and I'm on node 16.

Comment: Nodejs's issue reported in that other question, which was fixed in 20.10, was ported to node16 recently. You might be able to port it to your environment just by upgrading your local node 16 to the latest release