# NodeJS memory usage limit capped at 16GB under Linux

Tags: node.js, linux, memory

Unlike similar questions related to memory management in NodeJS apps, we do not want to limit. We plan to intensively utilize memory for our NodeJS app. However, AWS server crashes reporting a memory limit of 16GB. I've created a script that reproduces the issue on all reasonable versions of NodeJS under Linux. The script runs fine on Windows (Windows 10) and MacOS machines (with enough RAM or using swap file). But fails on Linux always at the same point.

```
'use strict';

const v8 = require('v8');

const format = n => {
    const lbls = ['B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB'];
    let i = 0;
    while (n / 1024 > 1) {
        n /= 1024;
        i++;
    }

    return `${Math.round(n * 100) / 100} ${lbls[i]}`;
};

const formatTime = ms => {
    const hours = Math.floor(ms/(1000 * 60 * 60));
    ms %= (1000 * 60 * 60);
    const minutes = Math.floor(ms/(1000 * 60));
    ms %= (1000 * 60);
    const seconds = Math.floor(ms/1000);
    ms %= 1000;
    return `${hours ? `${hours}h` : ''}${minutes ? `${minutes}m` : ''}${seconds ? `${seconds}` : '0'}.${ms}s`;
};

const generateLongString = (size, stats, reportMemEveryNIterations = 1e5) => {
    let str = '';
    let i = 0;
    while (str.length < size) {
        str += Math.random().toString();
        i += 1;
        if (i % reportMemEveryNIterations === 0) {
            const heap = v8.getHeapStatistics().used_heap_size;
            if (heap > stats.maxHeap)
                stats.maxHeap = heap;

            console.log(`${format(heap)} / ${format(stats.maxHeap)}, elapsed: ${formatTime(Date.now() - stats.startedAt)}`);
        }
    }

    return str;
}
const fillArrayOfStrings = (arr, stats, elementSize) => {
    console.log(`Start filling array[${arr.length}] with ${format(elementSize)} elements from scratch.`);
    for (let i= 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = generateLongString(elementSize, stats, 15e5);
    }
};

(async () => {
    const state = new Array(50);
    const stats = { maxHeap: 0, maxArrays: 0, startedAt: Date.now() };
    const iterationsCount = 1;
    for (let i = 0; i < iterationsCount; i++) {
        console.log(`Iteration #${i}/${iterationsCount}`);
        await fillArrayOfStrings(state, stats, 1e8);
    }

    console.log(`Max heap used: ${format(stats.maxHeap)}`);
    console.log(`Total time: ${formatTime(Date.now() - stats.startedAt)}`);
})();
```

Launch with extended old space: `node --max-old-space-size=24000 ./test.js`
Given script successfully completes occupying 18.28GB on Mac or Windows.

This is the typical result on any Linux:

```
...
15.51 GB / 15.51 GB, elapsed: 1m17.189s
15.61 GB / 15.61 GB, elapsed: 1m17.728s
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

The only slight change was observed on Node 12. It crashed after 15.85GB

Any hint is appreciated that would lead to the cause of the issue or possible workaround (without downgrading the host OS to insecure versions)

**Update**:
The following AWS SKUs were tested: r6i.xlarge (32GB RAM), r6g.xlarge (32GB RAM). With and without swap. Testing with swap was done inside docker container utilizing docker configuration to enforce swap usage: `--memory="8000m" --memory-swap="48000m"` (actually the system avoids swapping with abundance of RAM).
However, tests revealed that memory configuration is irrelevant to the issue. With or without swap usage hard limit remains the same.

Another interesting fact, which supports that system allows the process to use more memory, is a modification of the script that occupies memory with `Buffer`. As known, inside NodeJS this structures use different memory: `process.memoryUsage().arrayBuffers` or `v8.getHeapStatistics().external_memory`. This script allows to use all available memory even on Linux.

Personally, I suspect this issue can be related to [this one](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/51375) on NodeJs repository (glibc v2.28+ being the culprit). But I failed to verify this so far.

Comment: What AWS SKU are you trying to run this on? Do you have any swap enabled? If so, how much swap is reserved?

Comment: @esqew I've updated the question with information you asked

Answer (score 1):

Got to increase max mapped pages count per process.
Obviously on mentioned OSes it has a limit of 65530.

In short:

`vm.max_map_count=655300`
in `/etc/sysctl.conf` file.

Detailed answer on SO:
[Node.js heap out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558989/node-js-heap-out-of-memory/59923848#59923848)

Discussion of [issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/27715) at github/NodeJS