javascript - heap out of memory
i have api in nodejs for read data from mysql database and write it into csv file and download file after complete write in csv file. when i have 1.7 million records in database it is working but now i have 5 million record it is give me error
javascript - heap out of memory

my api code:
exports.exportdatatocsv = async (req, res) => {
    con.query(
        "SELECT sender_name, table_name FROM sender_tbl where sender_name ",
        function (error, data) {
            if (error) {
                console.error(error);
                res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
                return;
            }

            var mysqlData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
            var workbook = new ExcelJS.stream.xlsx.WorkbookWriter({ stream: res });

            mysqlData.forEach((sender, index) => {
                var worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet(
                    sender.sender_name.substring(0, 31)
                );

                con.query(
                    `SELECT * FROM ${sender.table_name} ORDER BY id DESC`,
                    function (error, tableData) {
                        if (error) {
                            console.error(error);
                            res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
                            return;
                        }

                        var fileHeader = [
                            "message",
                            "info",
                            "credit/debit",
                            "amount",
                            "netbal",
                        ];
                        worksheet.addRow(fileHeader);

                        tableData.forEach((row) => {
                            worksheet.addRow([
                                row.message,
                                row.info,
                                row.isdebit ? "debit" : "credit",
                                row.amount,
                                row.netbal,
                            ]);
                        });

                        if (index === mysqlData.length - 1) {
                            workbook
                                .commit()
                                .then(function () {
                                    res.status(200).end();
                                })
                                .catch(function (err) {
                                    console.error(err);
                                    res
                                        .status(500)
                                        .send("Error occurred while generating Excel file");
                                });
                        }
                    }
                );
            });
        }
    );
};

i have implement stream but still not working and i do not have to much idea regarding stream

"17 lakhs records" ... what unit is this "lakhs"?

Please don't use local words like lakh. People elsewhere aren't going to understand you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558989/node-js-heap-out-of-memory

Which line is throwing the error?

Node has a default max memory usage of less than 2GB on some 64bit systems depending on the Node runtime version. This can cause unexpected memory issues when running.
It's possible to adjust the max memory ceiling using a command-line flag passed into Node:
node --max-old-space-size=8192 your_script.js // 8192MB = 8GB

If you want to ensure all the forked node process want to run with this setting, use this
NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096 node your_script.js // 4GB

Your code executes too many db query calls at the same time even its look like callbacks.
so what we have to do is simply sequentialise the execution.
This can achieved through promises, I've used util.promisify so we don't need too much nested callback
//your imports +
const {promisify} = require('node:util');
const db = promisify(con.query);

exports.exportdatatocsv = async (req, res) => {
    let fileHeader = [
        "message",
        "info",
        "credit/debit",
        "amount",
        "netbal",
    ];
    
    try{
        const workbook = new ExcelJS.stream.xlsx.WorkbookWriter({ stream: res });
        const mysqlData = await db('SELECT sender_name, table_name FROM sender_tbl where sender_name').then(data => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)));
        for(sender of mysqlData){

            let worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet(
                sender.sender_name.substring(0, 31)
            );

            const tableData = await db(`SELECT * FROM ${sender.table_name} ORDER BY id DESC`);
            
            worksheet.addRow(fileHeader);

            tableData.forEach((row) => {
                worksheet.addRow([
                    row.message,
                    row.info,
                    row.isdebit ? "debit" : "credit",
                    row.amount,
                    row.netbal,
                ]);
            });
        }

        await workbook.commit();
        res.status(200).end();

    }catch(e){
        res.status(500).send(e.message);
    }
};

Thank to promisify to make the code more readable.

i have already use this solution but it not works

@LJCREATION I've edited the answer, try this may take some time but works
